# February Answerathon - last man standing competition - WINNER JoErNanO

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, fun, competitions

To give people time to enter, this will start on February 6th, UTC at midnight.

Rules: To stay in the competition, you must:

- answer an [unanswered question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered) not asked by you AND receive an upvote.
- to prevent the advantage some timezones may have, if there's no [unanswered question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered) you can answer, then you can answer a [new question asked in the previous 24 hours](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions) (also can't be your own question, and your answer still needs upvotes)
- **once the upvote has occurred (and not earlier)), edit the latest answer on this page for the date in question, and someone else can review and confirm.**
- IF there are no [unanswered questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered) at all (hah), then and only then can you answer a previously-answered question for your day.

Each 'day' will last for 48 hours.  So Feb 6th-7th inclusive is a day, Feb 8th-9th is a day, and so on.

Miss a 'day' and you're out.

*However, please - if we finally hit a day where you can't answer something with 
a proper answer, ie with a citation or evidence or something useful to the author, don't post a weak answer on a question.*

To give it time to sink in and in case I've missed some edge case, we'll have a practice 'day' on Feb 2nd.  I'll provide the sample answer template below.

Comment: I am in........

Comment: @MeNoTalk May I suggest editing your name into the answer below for Feb 2nd. We'll try and have only one answer for each date, with all the names and questions in it :)

Comment: @MarkMayo How do I enter?

Comment: @QuyNguyen2013  did you read the above? Just follow the instructions there. If something isn't clear please let me know. Answer an unanswered question for the correct 'day' and edit your name into the appropriate answer below. We've done Feb 2nd as an example day, properly starts on the 6th.

Comment: @MarkMayo I gwt it now :)

Comment: By `unanswered` do you mean with zero answers or without any accepted answers?

Comment: @JoErNanO zero answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the competition has ended.

Comment: @MeNoTalk ended? It continues until we have a winner!

Comment: @MarkMayo so one answer can be here and in March's one?

Comment: @MeNoTalk see rules in March one:
"IF you are part of the February answerathon and it's still going, you CANNOT use the same answer to enter both competitions. You'll have to answer two."

Comment: @MarkMayo LOL, I thought the rules are copy&paste from this post.. sorry :)

Comment: I guess by the end of this year, I will have to answer 11 answers every day..

Comment: If you think you can ;) They have to be quality, upvoted answers of course :D

Comment: Congrats @JoErNanO!!!!!!

Comment: @MarkMayo So what do I win? :D

Comment: @JoErNanO The title of Reigning Answerathon Champion ;) Defend it with your life!

Answer (score 3):

### March 24th - CLOSED - JoErNanO won after 24 "days"

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=utc+time&ia=answer) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name -------- Link to Answer in new question  ------- Reviewed by

1. Vince -
2. JoErNanO - [Which is the best exit from metro Montparnasse to get to Avenue du Maine northbound direction?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45137/22140) - Dirty-flow

Answer (score 1):

### February 26th - CLOSED -  5 contestants survived

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name -------- Link to Answer in new question  ------- Reviewed by

1. Mark Mayo - [Will there be flowers blooming in the last week of March at the St. Louis Botanical Garden?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43893/will-there-be-flowers-blooming-in-the-last-week-of-march-at-the-st-louis-botani/43920#43920) - JoErNanO
2. Vince - [Do we need a transit visa we have a 12 hour stop over and have booked a hotel, we are flying with AirIndia from Sydney to Rome return](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42274/do-we-need-a-transit-visa-we-have-a-12-hour-stop-over-and-have-booked-a-hotel-w/43913#43913) - Dirty-flow
3. MeNoTalk - [Is a regulation baggie required for carryon liquids in Toronto Pearson Airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43875/is-a-regulation-baggie-required-for-carryon-liquids-in-toronto-pearson-airport/43876#43876) - Dirty-flow
4. Relaxed - [Airplane seat dimension regulations: are there any?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43915/airplane-seat-dimension-regulations-are-there-any/43919#43919) - Dirty-flow
5. JoErNanO - [Car insurance in France for 100 days](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/43865/22140) - Dirty-flow

Answer (score 1):

### March 18th - CLOSED -  Vince and JoErNanO are still in the game

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name -------- Link to Answer in new question  ------- Reviewed by

1. Vince - 
   [Can I live on an unoccupied island?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44887/can-i-live-in-unoccupied-island/44888#44888) - Dirty-flow
2. JoErNanO - [When driving in Belgium, what equipment is mandatory to have in a car registered in another country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44822/22140) - Dirty-flow

Answer (score 0):

### February 6th - CLOSED! 7 successful entrants.

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

Mark Mayo - [Egyptian student - was refused tourist visa from UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/42991/101) - Dirty-flow

RoflcoptrException - [Get to El Calafate from the end of the W-Trek (Torres del Paine)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42948/get-to-el-calafate-from-the-end-of-the-w-trek-torres-del-paine/43013#43013) - Mark Mayo

Vince - [LDW / LIS for US car rental booked in UK](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35813/ldw-lis-for-us-car-rental-booked-in-uk/43002#43002) - Mark Mayo

MeNoTalk - [Small historical stone bridge in the North of Seoul](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43015/small-historical-stone-bridge-in-the-north-of-seoul/43017#43017) - Vince

Relaxed - [Is the 5 euro coin accepted anywhere?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43028/5-%E2%82%AC-coin-not-accepted/43029#43029) - Mark Mayo

Quy - [Can I get Diamox over the counter in Nairobi?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42458/can-i-get-diamox-over-the-counter-in-nairobi/43030#43030) - Mark Mayo

JoErNanO - [On arrival visa at Doha for Philippine citizen, currently holding UAE visa as Technical Adviser](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43041/on-arrival-visa-at-doha-for-philippine-citizen-currently-holding-uae-visa-as-te/43045#43045) - Mark Mayo

Comment: I can't edit it.

Comment: @QuyNguyen2013 can you go to the chat on the main site?

Comment: @QuyNguyen2013 ah you need 2k rep. I've changed it to a community wiki answer, should only need 100 now, try again?

Answer (score 0):

### February 8th - CLOSED! 7 contestants remain.

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. Mark Mayo - [How many days a year is a U.S. citizen allowed to stay in Morocco?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42808/how-many-days-a-year-is-a-u-s-citizen-allowed-to-stay-in-morocco/43067#43067) - Quy
2. RoflcoptrException - [Where are the Himalayan Buddhist stupas?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43114/where-are-the-himalayan-buddhist-stupas/43126#43126) - MeNoTalk
3. Vince - [Affordable taxi service from BUF Airport to Niagara Falls on Canadian side](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39090/affordable-taxi-service-from-buf-airport-to-niagara-falls-on-canadian-side) - MeNoTalk
4. MeNoTalk - [Chinatown in Seoul](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43072/chinese-town-in-seoul/43073) - JoErNanO
5. Relaxed - [Reapplying for a Schengen visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27792/reapplying-for-a-schengen-visa) - MeNoTalk
6. Quy -  [Are there any power outlets and Wi-Fi hotspots on the Zurich-Milan train?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43062/are-there-any-power-outlets-and-wi-fi-hotspots-on-the-zurich-milan-train/43068#43068) - Mark Mayo
7. JoErNanO - [Petrol prices in New Zealand](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/43079/22140) - Vince

Comment: Please community-wikify this :)

Comment: @QuyNguyen2013 done

Answer (score 0):

### February 10th - CLOSED -  7 contestants survived.

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. Mark Mayo - [Passport blank page requirements for Kurdistan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42670/passport-blank-page-requirements-for-kurdistan) - Quy
2. RoflcoptrException - [What is the most campsite-dense route between Belgium and the Tatras?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30452/what-is-the-most-campsite-dense-route-between-belgium-and-the-tatras) - JoErNanO
3. Vince - [What time do air conditioned buses run from Colombo to Anuradhapura?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34294/what-time-do-air-conditioned-buses-run-from-colombo-to-anuradhapura) - JoErNanO
4. MeNoTalk - [Driving in Guatemala on a US license - must you carry your passport as well?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43178/driving-in-guatemala-on-a-us-license/43179#43179) - Flimzy
5. Relaxed - [12 hour stopover in Istanbul (Atatürk)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43197/12-hour-stopover-in-istanbul-atat%C3%BCrk) - Vince
6. Quy -  [Food imports and exports from Turkey](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43130/food-imports-and-exports-from-turkey/43141#43141) - Mark Mayo
7. JoErNanO - [Travel from Arabba Ski Region to Venice](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43135/travel-from-arabba-ski-region-to-venice) - Mark Mayo

Answer (score 0):

### February 12th - CLOSED -  6 contestants remain, Quy is out! Better luck next time.

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. Mark Mayo - [Are American Express credit cards widely accepted in Japan, specifically, Osaka?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43228/are-american-express-credit-cards-widely-accepted-in-japan-specifically-osaka/43230#43230) - JoErNanO
2. RoflcoptrException - [Walk from San Sebastian to Picos de Europa in 3 days with some hitch-hiking?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34956/walk-from-san-sebastian-to-picos-de-europa-in-3-days-with-some-hitch-hiking/43297#43297) - JoErNanO
3. Vince - [Is there a site with all airlines carry-on restrictions?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42312/is-there-a-site-with-all-airlines-carry-on-restrictions/43221#43221) - Relaxed
4. MeNoTalk - [Can I travel to Romania with schengen visa issued by the embassy of The Netherlands and staying for a longer period in Romania than in Amsterdam?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43265/can-i-travel-to-romania-with-schengen-visa-issued-by-the-embassy-of-the-netherla) - JoErNanO
5. Relaxed - [Least Strict Schengen Visa Application? - France or Italy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43258/least-strict-schengen-visa-application-france-or-italy) - MeNoTalk
6. Quy -
7. JoErNanO - [Should I tip my Airbnb host?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43256/should-i-tip-airbnb-host-in-u-s) - Vince

Comment: @MenoTalk - rolled back, you can't review your own entries :) From the rules: "and someone else can review and confirm."

Comment: I actually reviewd Relaxed's post.. but by mistake I added it to mine!

Answer (score 0):

### February 14th - CLOSED -  5 contestants remain

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. Mark Mayo - [Does the UK have any constraint on work permit for previous Chinese work permit holders?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38721/does-uk-have-any-constraint-on-work-permit-for-previous-chinese-work-permit-hold/43348#43348) -
   JoErNanO
2. RoflcoptrException -
3. Vince - 
   [Cooking my own meals in Fajardo Puerto Rico](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/43091/22140) - JoErNanO
4. MeNoTalk - [Documents required for B2 at airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43326/documents-required-for-b2-at-airport/43328#43328) - JoErNanO
5. Relaxed - [Schengen visa transit in other Schengen country](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43354/schengen-visa-transit-in-other-schengen-country) - MeNoTalk
6. JoErNanO - [Do additional guest need to be present for hotel check in](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/43336/22140) - MeNoTalk

Answer (score 0):

### February 16th - CLOSED -  5 contestants succeeded

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. Mark Mayo - [Why aren't micro Swiss Army multitools allowed on the plane but small scissors are allowed?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43323/why-arent-micro-swiss-army-multitools-allowed-on-the-plane-but-small-scissors-a/43395#43395) - Dirty-flow
2. Vince - [How flexible are around the world tickets regarding flight dates?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/43176/22140) - JoErNanO
3. MeNoTalk - [Tipping in shared ride vans](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43405/tipping-in-shared-ride-vans/43414#43414) - Dirty-flow
4. Relaxed - [Best way to leave EU with expired visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43374/best-way-to-leave-eu-with-expired-visa) - Mark Mayo
5. JoErNanO - [What do shops mean when they are open 7/7?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/43440/22140) - Mark Mayo

Answer (score 0):

### February 18th - CLOSED -  5 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. Mark Mayo - [Is there such a thing as a European sim card?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43477/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-european-sim-card/43479#43479) - Vince
2. Vince - [Bus from Monteverde to Liberia, Costa Rica](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38986/bus-from-monteverde-to-liberia-costa-rica/43491#43491) - MeNoTalk
3. MeNoTalk - [Can I have a sword fight in Scotland?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43540/can-i-have-a-sword-fight-in-scotland/43541#43541) - Mark Mayo
4. Relaxed - [Difference between Schengen Tourist and Business Visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43422/difference-between-schengen-tourist-and-business-visa/43548#43548) - Mark Mayo
5. JoErNanO - [Type D student visa in Spain: valid date and duration of stay](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/43497/22140) - Vince

Answer (score 0):

### February 20th- CLOSED -  5 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. Mark Mayo - [Check in time for layover at Sydney airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43078/check-in-time-for-layover-at-sydney-airport/43631#43631) - MeNoTalk
2. Vince - [How can I search specifically for cottages/cabins with kitchen(ettes)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35784/how-can-i-search-specifically-for-cottages-cabins-with-kitchenettes) - JoErNanO
3. MeNoTalk - [Is it rude to refuse to eat from the same plate in parts of the Middle East?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43639/is-it-rude-to-refuse-to-eat-from-the-same-plate-in-parts-of-the-middle-east/43644#43644) - Mark Mayo
4. Relaxed - [Indian having UK visa. Can I get a Schengen visa on arrival at France?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43642/indian-having-uk-visa-can-i-get-a-schengen-visa-on-arrival-at-france/43646#43646) - MeNoTalk
5. JoErNanO - [When buying fuel in Peru service stations, do you have to give an ID?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43588/when-buying-fuel-in-peru-service-stations-do-you-have-to-give-an-id) - Vince

Comment: If someone can make the Feb 22nd one in 10 hours or so, I'm totally not going to have access to a computer most of the day.

Answer (score 0):

### February 22nd- CLOSED -  5 contestants survived

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. Mark Mayo - [Is there a Waze-like app to keep track of each other among travel companions?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43701/is-there-a-waze-like-app-to-keep-track-of-each-other-among-travel-companions/43702#43702) - JoErNanO
2. Vince - [What are the transportation options for getting from Managua International Airport to other cities in Nicaragua?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42903/what-are-the-transportation-options-for-getting-from-managua-international-airpo/43746#43746) - JoErNanO
3. MeNoTalk - [I have B1 visa, can I apply for F1 visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43704/i-have-b1-visa-can-i-apply-for-f1-visa/43728#43728) - Vince
4. Relaxed - [Flight connections between south-west Germany and Corsica?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43714/flight-connections-between-south-west-germany-and-corsica) - MeNoTalk
5. JoErNanO - [Can a visitor to the UK work as volunteer?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/43690/22140) - Vince

Comment: Can someone update this on the 24th at 0.00, I'm going to be on a boat and unable to do it :/

Comment: @markmayo Done.

Answer (score 0):

### February 24th - CLOSED -  5 contestants survived

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name -------- Link to Answer in new question  ------- Reviewed by

1. Mark Mayo - [12-hour Daytime Luggage Storage in San Juan, Puerto Rico?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43780/12-hour-daytime-luggage-storage-in-san-juan-puerto-rico/43845#43845) - MeNoTalk
2. Vince - [Will I get a better deal if I were to book a car from an airline reservation web site?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43834/will-i-get-a-better-deal-if-i-were-to-book-a-car-from-an-airline-reservation-web/43837#43837) - JoErNanO
3. MeNoTalk - [Airport employees in preclearance areas?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43817/airport-employees-in-preclearance-areas/43824#43824) - Vince
4. Relaxed - [How can I get to Iceland on a cargo ship?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43840/how-can-i-get-to-iceland-on-a-cargo-ship) - Vince
5. JoErNanO - [Is it safe to park hired 2 wheeler near Goa beaches?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/43788/22140) - Vince

Answer (score 0):

### February 28th - CLOSED  5 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name -------- Link to Answer in new question  ------- Reviewed by

1. Mark Mayo - [How to get from Istanbul Airport (Atatürk) to Bursa, mid March, by bus and ferry?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43764/how-to-get-from-istanbul-airport-ataturk-to-bursa-mid-march-by-bus-and-ferry/43971#43971) - MeNoTalk
2. Vince - [Hiking/nature around Lyon](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43941/hiking-nature-around-lyon/43944#43944) - MeNoTalk
3. MeNoTalk - [Finding Gilgit's Kargah Buddha](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43908/finding-gilgits-kargah-buddha/43954#43954) - JoErNanO
4. Relaxed - [Duty free when flying to two different EU countries with 2 litres of spirits?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43952/duty-free-when-flying-to-two-different-eu-countries-with-2-litres-of-spirits/43953#43953) - Mark Mayo
5. JoErNanO - [Air travel with a stoma (ileostomy or colostomy)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43035/air-travel-with-a-stoma-ileostomy-or-colostomy) - Mark Mayo

Answer (score 0):

### March 2nd - CLOSED -  5 contestants survived

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name -------- Link to Answer in new question  ------- Reviewed by

1. Mark Mayo - [How long does my Indian visa need to be active after I have entered into India?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43864/how-long-does-my-indian-visa-need-to-be-active-after-i-have-entered-into-india/44013#44013) - Vince
2. Vince - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/44078/3044 - JoErNanO
3. MeNoTalk - [Is the use of APC Kiosks quicker than the paper method](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42128/is-the-use-of-apc-kiosks-quicker-than-the-paper-method/44087#44087) - JoErNanO
4. Relaxed - [Splitting my 90 days in a Schengen country](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44018/splitting-my-90-days-in-a-schengen-country) - Vince
5. JoErNanO - [Are wet wipes subject to the TSA's 3-1-1 Liquids Rule?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44043/22140) - Vince

Answer (score 0):

### March 4th - CLOSED -  4 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name -------- Link to Answer in new question  ------- Reviewed by

1. Mark Mayo -
2. Vince - [Why do airlines (typically?) require customers to phone for special meals, and not provide this option online?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44099/why-do-airlines-typically-require-customers-to-phone-for-special-meals-and-n/44104#44104) - JoErNanO
3. MeNoTalk - [Korea: Visa required to go to the city while in transit in Seoul for a Philippine citizen?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44194/korea-visa-required-to-go-to-the-city-while-in-transit-in-seoul-for-a-philippin/44215#44215)
4. Relaxed - [Is there an easyJet ticket office in Schönefeld?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44172/easyjet-ticket-office-in-sch%C3%B6nefeld) - Vince
5. JoErNanO - [Where can I leave 15kg luggage in Osaka for 5 days?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44112/22140) - Vince

Comment: Vince, community-wikify this. ;)

Comment: @JoErNanO That's not really necessary anymore.

Answer (score 0):

### March 6th - CLOSED -  4 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name -------- Link to Answer in new question  ------- Reviewed by

1. Vince - [Is it Reasonable to book Ferries from Santorini to Mykonos in Advance?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44288/is-it-reasonable-to-book-ferries-from-santorini-to-mykonos-in-advance/44291#44291)
2. MeNoTalk - [European driver's license Type B and 10,000lb vehicle in USA](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44276/european-drivers-license-type-b-and-10-000lb-vehicle-in-usa/44285#44285) - Vince
3. Relaxed - [Schengen visa application for multiple trips?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44233/schengen-visa-application-for-multiple-trips) - JoErNanO
4. JoErNanO - [Service to carry bags to / from airport in Australia - right up to checkin?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44228/22140) - Relaxed

Answer (score 0):

### March 8th - CLOSED-  3 contestants elbow to elbow

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name -------- Link to Answer in new question  ------- Reviewed by

1. Vince - [Historical flight data outside of the USA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44263/historical-flight-data-outside-of-the-usa/44336#44336) - Dirty-flow
2. MeNoTalk - [Who was this persistent person at Shanghai airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44350/who-was-this-persistent-person-at-shanghai-airport/44354#44354) - JoErNanO
3. Relaxed -
4. JoErNanO - [Hotels/cottages with private hot tub access in Colorado Springs/Denver, Colorado](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44142/22140) - Vince

Answer (score 0):

### March 10th - CLOSED -  2 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name -------- Link to Answer in new question  ------- Reviewed by

1. Vince - [Free Amtrak Lounge Access with No Ticket](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44444/free-amtrak-lounge-access-with-no-ticket/44446#44446) - JoErNanO
2. MeNoTalk -
3. JoErNanO - [Practical food to take on flight without anything served?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44451/22140) - Dirty-flow

Answer (score 0):

### March 12th - CLOSED -  2 contestants elbow to elbow

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name -------- Link to Answer in new question  ------- Reviewed by

1. Vince - [Do I need a Chilean identification number just to buy a bus ticket?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44536/do-i-need-a-chilean-identification-number-just-to-buy-a-bus-ticket/44538#44538) - JoErNanO
2. JoErNanO - [Luggage storage for a few hours in Las Vegas?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44525/22140) - Dirty-flow

Answer (score 0):

### March 14th - CLOSED -  2 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name -------- Link to Answer in new question  ------- Reviewed by

1. Vince - [Long Layover in Zurich Airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44628/long-layover-in-zurich-airport/44639#44639) - 
   JoErNanO
2. JoErNanO - [Which car should we rent to visit several European countries?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44580/22140) - Vince

Answer (score 0):

### March 16th - CLOSED -  2 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name -------- Link to Answer in new question  ------- Reviewed by

1. Vince - [Why is there usually free cancellation on car rentals but not on hotels?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44746/why-is-there-usually-free-cancellation-on-car-rentals-but-not-on-hotels/44758#44758) - JoErNanO
2. JoErNanO - [Can I supervise a learner italian driver in italy with my full Australian drivers license plus international drivers permit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44738/22140) - Dirty-flow

Answer (score 0):

### March 20th - CLOSED - Vince and JoErNanO are still in the game - for how long ?

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=utc+time&ia=answer) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name -------- Link to Answer in new question  ------- Reviewed by

1. Vince - [Can I create a travel money card as tourist?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44975/can-i-create-a-travel-money-card-as-tourist/44985#44985) - JoErNanO
2. JoErNanO - [What are good options for long term parking at O'Hare Airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44024/22140) - Vince

Answer (score 0):

### March 22nd - CLOSED -  Vince and JoErNanO are still in the game

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=utc+time&ia=answer) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name -------- Link to Answer in new question  ------- Reviewed by

1. Vince - [Could I use American Express rewards points for Eurostar](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45030/could-i-use-american-express-rewards-points-for-eurostar/45045#45045) - JoErNanO
2. JoErNanO - [What are Android and/or iOS apps for public transit directions in Istanbul, Turkey?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45020/22140) - Dirty-flow