# March Answerathon - WINNER: JoErNanO

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, fun, competitions

To give people time to enter, this will start on March 1st, UTC at midnight.

Rules: To stay in the competition, you must:

- answer an [unanswered question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered) not asked by you AND receive an upvote for your answer.
- **once the upvote has occurred (and not earlier)), edit the latest answer on this page for the date in question, and someone else can review and confirm.**
- IF there are no [unanswered questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered) at all (hah), then and only then can you answer a previously-answered question for your 'day'.
- IF you are [part of the February answerathon](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3015/february-answerathon-last-man-standing-competition) and it's still going, you CANNOT use the same answer to enter both competitions. You'll have to answer two.

Each 'day' will last for 48 hours.  So March 1st-2nd inclusive is a day, March 3rd-4th is a day, and so on.

Miss a 'day' and you're out.

*However, please - if we finally hit a day where you can't answer something with 
a proper answer, ie with a citation or evidence or something useful to the author, don't post a weak answer on a question.*

I'll provide the sample answer template below for  March 1st. If you intend to enter, put your name there now.

Comment: Hrm, isn't travel SE too small for this? There are only 15 questions a day per http://stackexchange.com/sites and from the past, only 93 unanswered (wow).

Comment: @chx - well the [February one](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3015/february-answerathon-last-man-standing-competition) worked fine (still going).  IF we end up with zero unanswered questions, as described above - then we can answer a previously answered question.  But that seems unlikely - it's more likely that people will drop out for time, or inability to answer the few 'tough ones' remaining. And if it helps reduce the unanswered ones, all the better.

Comment: It's an experiment for fun anyway.  If it succeeds like the Feb one seems to have, great (although that started with like 140 unanswered), and if it fails now as it gets too hard, well, it means we've answered some good questions, hopefully.

Comment: Must the answer be posted and upvoted within the two-day time window for it to count? Or can I maybe answer today, get an upvote in a week and count my answer for whatever that competition day might be?

Comment: @JoErNanO upvote has to be in window too, otherwise you can't write the entry below (as per rules), and the day would close without you entering.  Generally really good answers get upvotes pretty fast any day of the week.

Comment: If the intent was to burn the unanswered page to the ground, it's at 55... that's crazy.

Comment: @chx we're getting there :) It's certainly effective.

Comment: @MarkMayo we are well on the way to be the second StackExchange site with more than 10k questions and 100% answer rate http://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered Currently only roleplaying is such.

Comment: @chx assuming it rounds, when we get below 50 we should hit there....is what I've been tracking for. (crosses fingers)

Comment: Actually we are at 11k questions so it should hit 100% real soon.

Comment: @chx, yeah we're at more than 99.5% or something, should round like now :/  RPG has 37 left, so you definitely don't need every question answered to get 100.

Answer (score 2):

### April 20th - CLOSED - Winner: JoErNanO

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [Multiple-entry visas on arrival in Kathmandu](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/46397/22140) - chx
2. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) -

Comment: @chx What happened man?

Comment: Noone upvoted my answers in time.

Answer (score 1):

### March 9th - CLOSED - 5 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [MeNoTalk](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/10051/menotalk) - [Re-Applying for Schengen Visa in Germany as Visiting family and Friends Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44437/re-applying-for-schengen-visa-in-germany-as-visiting-family-and-friends-visa) - JoErNanO
2. [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [Where to return I-94 form?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44389/where-to-return-i-94-form/44393#44393) - JoErNanO
3. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [Is a driving licence needed to drive a scooter in Ibiza?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44440/22140) - Vince
4. [RoryAlsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop) - [How to apply for a Moroccan visa from Tehran?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44372/1381) - 
   JoErNanO
5. [Relaxed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6669/relaxed)-
6. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Do I need a transit visa in Dubai?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44359/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-in-dubai/44362#44362) - MeNoTalk

Answer (score 0):

### March 1st - CLOSED - 7 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) - [Use of Euros in Sri Lanka, will they be accepted for small purchases?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43866/use-of-euros-in-sri-lanka-will-they-be-accepted-for-small-purchases/44014#44014) - Rory Alsop
2. [MeNoTalk](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/10051/menotalk) - [What's the courtesy: wipe off the wash basin?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43977/whats-the-courtesy-wipe-off-the-wash-basin/43978#43978) - JoErNanO
3. [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [What is the fastest bus route from Guatemala City to Cancún, Mexico?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/40647/what-is-the-fastest-bus-route-from-guatemala-city-to-canc%C3%BAn-mexico/44041#44041) - Rory Alsop
4. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - 
   [What is a cheap way to get from NYC to Boston, MA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44002/22140) - Mark Mayo
5. [RoryAlsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop) - [In the Grenadines, how could you get scuba tanks for diving if already on a boat?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/40078/in-the-grenadines-how-could-you-get-scuba-tanks-for-diving-if-already-on-a-boat/44033#1381) - Vince
6. Quy -
7. nic -
8. [Relaxed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6669/relaxed) - [Schengen 90 days: what's counted?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44021/schengen-90-days-whats-counted) - Rory Alsop
9. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Prepaid SIM card with best data plan in Canada](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43958/prepaid-sim-card-with-best-data-plan-in-canada/44015#44015) - Vince

Comment: You guys with your profile links in the post, you are show-offs. :P

Comment: Erm...Fixed that for ya JoE

Comment: @roryalsop Aaaaaah, equality. :)

Comment: @JoErNanO you made 7k+ rep in 4 months, that's better than MarkMayo and way better than me..

Comment: If someone can create the March 3rd one in 6 hours or so - I'll be without devices for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

### March 3rd - CLOSED - 6 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) -
2. [MeNoTalk](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/10051/menotalk) - [Which is the best time of year to visit Bali?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44133/which-is-the-best-time-of-year-to-visit-bali/44137#44137) - JoErNanO
3. [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [Travelling to San Francisco from Dublin to save money on tax- allowed?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44092/travelling-to-san-francisco-from-dublin-to-save-money-on-tax-allowed/44100#44100) - JoErNanO
4. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [Taking the CTA to United Center, Chicago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44080/22140) - Rory Alsop
5. [RoryAlsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop) - [How do I use a Satnav (Garmin Nuvi 2599) in Turkey?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/40258/22140) - JoErNanO
6. [Relaxed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6669/relaxed) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44106/slavery-and-kidnapping-risks-in-kazakhstan-is-there-a-real-threat-to-be-kidnapp/44110#44110 - JoErNanO
7. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Healthcare and dual citizenship](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44098/healthcare-and-dual-citizenship/44103#44103) - JoErNanO

Comment: @joernano make the answer as a wiki so people with less rep can edit it.

Comment: Would love to but I can't do it from the online app. Give me time to login from a computer. ;)

Answer (score 0):

### March 5th - CLOSED - 6 contestants survived

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [MeNoTalk](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/10051/menotalk) - [Pass for public transport in San Francisco](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44267/pass-for-public-transport-insan-francisco) - Vince
2. [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [Going from SFO Airport to San Francisco downtown](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44257/going-from-sfo-airport-to-san-francisco-downtown/44273#44273) - MeNoTalk
3. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [Where can I see snake charmers in India?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44162/22140) - Rory Alsop
4. [RoryAlsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop) - [Driving a rental car through Colorado](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44169/driving-a-rental-car-through-colorado/44185#44185) - Relaxed
5. [Relaxed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6669/relaxed) - [Need to extend the validity (number of days) for an unused Schengen visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44176/need-to-extend-the-validity-number-of-days-for-an-unused-schengen-visa) - JoErNanO
6. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Is it true that people "can just take all the luggage off the airport conveyer belt and leave with it."?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44211/is-it-true-that-people-can-just-take-all-the-luggage-off-the-airport-conveyer-b/44212#44212) - Rory Alsop

Comment: chx - your post was 2nd answer...

Comment: There's also http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/44212/4188

Comment: updated for you chx

Answer (score 0):

### March 7th - CLOSED - 6 contestants survived

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [MeNoTalk](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/10051/menotalk) - [Can an airline really refuse to depart when overbooked?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44317/can-an-airline-really-refuse-to-depart-when-overbooked/44321#44321) - Rory Alsop
2. [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [Long Haul flight with 9 month old with potential no Bassinet](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44339/long-haul-flight-with-9-month-old-with-potential-no-bassinet/44340#44340) - Rory Alsop
3. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [Hiking around Vigo, Spain](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44287/22140) - Rory Alsop
4. [RoryAlsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop) - [Flying to a Schengen zone from a country other than the one where the visa was issued](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/36020/1381) - JoErNanO
5. [Relaxed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6669/relaxed) - [I am British, If I change my passport name, would other countries know my old name?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44300/i-am-british-if-i-change-my-passport-name-would-other-countries-know-my-old-na/44302#44302) - MeNoTalk
6. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Going from a VWP to being an overstay and now applying for a B2 visa with the intent of switching it to a student visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44283/going-from-a-vwp-to-being-an-overstay-and-now-applying-for-a-b2-visa-with-the-in/44284#44284) - 
   JoErNanO

Answer (score 0):

### March 11th - CLOSED - 5 contestants survived

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [MeNoTalk](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/10051/menotalk) - [American Allowance in Schengen Area vs Having a Schengen Visa in Schengen area](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44541/american-allowance-in-schengen-area-v-s-having-a-schengen-visa-in-schengen-area/44542#44542) - Vince
2. [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [Can I add passengers later for free to my booking for the DFDS Dover-Calais / Dunkirk ferry?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44374/can-i-add-passengers-later-for-free-to-my-booking-for-the-dfds-dover-calais-du/44493#44493) - 
   JoErNanO
3. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) -
   [How can I estimate how much sunscreen I need to pack?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44488/22140) - Vince
4. [RoryAlsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop) - [Is there a list of countries that do not reset the "clock" for Canada visits?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44462/1381) - chx
5. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Compensation for flight change made by the airline](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44464/compensation-for-flight-change-made-by-the-airline/44465#44465) - Rory Alsop

Answer (score 0):

### March 15th - CLOSED - 4 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [How long can I expect the connection to be in Athens International Airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44680/how-long-can-i-expect-the-connection-to-be-in-athens-international-airport/44706#44706) - Rory Alsop
2. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) -
   [Best 'private' spots for stargazing on Mountain Teide, Tenerife](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44269/22140) - Rory Alsop
3. [RoryAlsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop) - [What can I do in Hong Kong with a three hour layover?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44664/1381) - Dirty-flow
4. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [What to do with an invitation from a friend in UK whom I wish to visit during a short holiday there?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44534/what-to-do-with-an-invitation-from-a-friend-in-uk-whom-i-wish-to-visit-during-a/44618#44618) - 
   JoErNanO

Comment: This answerathon made us to answer a [question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44495/do-i-need-two-transit-visas-for-travelling-through-the-us/44643?noredirect=1#comment84125_44643) outstanding since '11. If you want, you can use that as my entry for March 15 if the one linked isn't good enough. :)

Answer (score 0):

### March 17th - CLOSED - 3 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [Is Pentecost observed in Lisbon?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44809/is-pentecost-observed-in-lisbon/44827#44827) - JoErNanO
2. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [How to access Killarney Provincial park (Ontario) by public transportation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44732/22140) - Rory Alsop
3. [RoryAlsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop) -
4. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Tourist visa with cancelled old passport and have renewed passport in hand](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44696/tourist-visa-with-cancelled-old-passport-and-have-renewed-passport-in-hand/44729#44729) - JoErNanO

Answer (score 0):

### March 19th - CLOSED - 3 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [Anything to do for a 4h35 stopover in Guangzhou?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44892/anything-tod-o-for-a-4h35-stopover-in-guangzhuo/44907#44907) - chx
2. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) -
   [Is it possible to bring fudge from New Zealand to UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44899/22140) - chx
3. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Emirates luggage size rules changed since Nov.15, 2014](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44780/emirates-luggage-size-rules-changed-since-nov-15-2014/44857#44857) - Mark Mayo

Comment: Hrm, you two, you still have the February one going too. I see we will be here for a very long time :D

Comment: @Vince and I are the tip of the sword! :P

Answer (score 0):

### March 21st - CLOSED - 3 contestants survived

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [Olympic National Park Rain Forest in April](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45025/olympic-national-park-rain-forest-in-april/45042#45042) - chx
2. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [What is the best way to travel cheap through Scotland?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44977/22140) - Vince
3. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [How long should I schedule to travel from Manila to General Santos, Philippines?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44945/how-long-should-i-schedule-to-travel-from-manila-to-general-santos-philippines/44962#44962) - Vince

Answer (score 0):

### March 25th - CLOSED - just 2 contestants remain!

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [Roissybus - No more child fare, but how about baby?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45167/22140) - Dirty-flow
2. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Can I enter the UK the day before the expiry date of my visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45157/can-i-enter-the-uk-the-day-before-the-expiry-date-of-my-visa/45158) - Dirty-flow

Comment: @Vince What happened man?!

Answer (score 0):

### March 27th - CLOSED - just 2 contestants remain!

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [If I know a flight is delayed can I turn up late for check-in at the airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45289/22140) - chx
2. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Colombian entering Colombia on day of Colombian passport expiry date, could I be refused entry?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45265/colombian-entering-colombia-on-day-of-colombian-passport-expiry-date-could-i-be/45266#45266) - JoErNanO

Answer (score 0):

### March 29th - OPEN - just 2 contestants remain!

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [What's the emergency number (the 911 equivalent) in Israel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45367/22140) - Vince
2. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Can a minor travel to the UK with an adult but return alone?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45315/can-a-minor-travel-to-the-uk-with-an-adult-but-return-alone/45351#45351) - JoErNanO

Answer (score 0):

### March 31st - OPEN - just 2 contestants remain!

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) -
   [Where is the jetty where you take the boat to visit the Embera communities?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45341/22140) - Mark Mayo
2. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Cheap Internet access in Cuba for tourists?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45244/internet-in-cuba-for-tourists/45421#45421) - Mark Mayo

Answer (score 0):

### April 2nd CLOSED - just 2 contestants remain!

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [Tokyo's Keikyu Airport Line transit question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45588/22140) - Mark Mayo
2. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Where might I observe people sneaking across the Vietnam-Cambodian border illegally?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45511/where-can-someone-sneak-across-the-vietnam-cambodian-border-illegally-i-need-in/45513#45513) - Vince

Answer (score 0):

### April 4th CLOSED - just 2 contestants remain!

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [Booking website has changed a part of my flight, can I ask a full refund?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45473/22140) - chx
2. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Can one travel with xerox copy of photo iD](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45602/can-one-travel-with-xerox-copy-of-photo-id/45603#45603) - JoErNanO

Comment: @chx, c'mon, don't let him win two in a row ;)

Answer (score 0):

### April 6th CLOSED - just 2 contestants remain!

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [Is autolib' a good mode of transportation for tourists in terms of available drop-off points](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45695/22140) - chx
2. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Can US tourist visa program be used after student exchange visa after visiting Canada and coming back to USA as tourist?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45660/can-us-tourist-visa-program-used-after-student-exchange-visa-after-visiting-to-c/45661#45660) - JoErNanO

Answer (score 0):

### April 8th CLOSED - just 2 contestants remain!

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) -
   [Long term Italian visa for Malaysian citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/30915/22140) - chx
2. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Walk from Mauritius MRU airport to Mahebourg?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/33948/walk-from-mauritius-mru-airport-to-mahebourg/45770#45770) - Vince

Answer (score 0):

### April 10th - CLOSED - just 2 contestants remain!

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) -
   [What is the most convenient possibility to rent a kayak for the Allier?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45952/22140) - chx
2. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Birth certificate problem for passport - two different locations?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45867/birth-certificate-problem-for-passport-two-different-locations/45869#45869) - Dirty-flow

Answer (score 0):

### April 12th - CLOSED - just 2 contestants remain!

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [What is good accommodation for festival (camp or hostel)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/46006/22140) - chx
2. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Schengen visa, in refugee travel document from USA](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45978/schengen-visa-in-refugee-travel-document-from-usa/45979#45979) - Vince

Answer (score 0):

### April 14th - CLOSED - just 2 contestants remain!

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [Japanese ryokan with a baby of 20 month](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/46107/22140) - Dirty-flow
2. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Is India's Jet Airways considered a budget airline?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46079/is-jet-airways-considered-a-budget-airline/46080#46080) - Mark Mayo

Answer (score 0):

### April 16th - CLOSED - just 2 contestants remain!

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) -  [Should I purchase train tickets between Milan Malpensa Airport and Florence on the day or book them in advance?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/46237/22140) - chx
2. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Connecting through UK when between UK visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46172/connecting-through-uk-when-between-uk-visas/46173#46173) - JoErNanO

Answer (score 0):

### April 18th - OPEN - just 2 contestants remain!

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [Visa requirements for Jamaica for an Indian citizen with a US visitor visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/46316/22140) = chx
2. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Any site for booking travel tickets for visa without paying?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46286/any-site-for-booking-travel-tickets-for-visa-without-paying/46297#46297) - JoErNanO

Answer (score -1):

### March 13th - CLOSED - 4 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [MeNoTalk](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/10051/menotalk) -
2. [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [Renting a car in the USA — how to know costs for the legal minimum liability insurance, before arriving for pickup?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44551/renting-a-car-in-the-usa-how-to-know-costs-for-liability-insurance/44572#44572) - chx
3. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) -
   [Where can I store my suitcase at Madrid Bajaras airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44550/22140) - Vince
4. [RoryAlsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop) - [Do I still need my Garmin Etrex Vista GPS or can I just use my iPhone with an App?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44523/1381) - Vince
5. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [As a UK passport holder do I need to get a Schengen Visa for Iceland for a 4 day holiday?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44553/as-a-uk-passport-holder-do-i-need-to-get-a-schengen-visa-for-iceland/44554#44554) - 
   JoErNanO

Answer (score -1):

### March 23rd - CLOSED - 2 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) -
2. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [What does an Oyster £5 One Day Bus and Tram Pass look like?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45101/22140) - chx
3. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [What do Amadeus GDS itinerary header codes mean?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45003/what-do-amadeus-gds-itinerary-header-codes-mean/45063#45063) - Vince