# April Answerathon - WINNER: Mark Mayo

Tags: discussion, fun, competitions

To give people time to enter, this will start on April 1st, UTC at midnight.

Rules: To stay in the competition, you must:

- answer an [unanswered question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered) not asked by you AND receive an upvote for your answer.
- **once the upvote has occurred (and not earlier)), edit the latest answer on this page for the date in question, and someone else can review and confirm.**
- IF there are no [unanswered questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered) at all (hah), then and only then can you answer a previously-answered question for your 'day'.
- IF the question you answer is marked as a duplicate on the same 'day', your answer is invalidated.
- IF you are [part of the February answerathon](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3015/february-answerathon-last-man-standing-competition) or [March answerathon](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3036/march-answerathon-active-3-contestants-remain) and it's still going, you CANNOT use the same answer to enter more than one competition. You'll have to answer a new question for each.

Each 'day' will last for 48 hours.  So April 1st-2nd inclusive is a day, April 3rd-4th is a day, and so on.

Miss a 'day' and you're out.

*However, please - if we finally hit a day where you can't answer something with 
a proper answer, ie with a citation or evidence or something useful to the author, don't post a weak answer on a question.*

I'll provide the sample answer template below for  April 1st. If you intend to enter, put your name there now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### April 19th - CLOSED - Mark Mayo wins

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) - [Are there any Canadian credit cards that offer medical insurance for 30 days for the secondary user?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46337/are-there-any-canadian-credit-cards-that-offer-medical-insurance-over-30-days/46344#46344) - Vince
2. [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) -
3. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) -

Comment: You got lucky, man. :P

Comment: Congrats @MarkMayo !

Answer (score 1):

### April 3rd - CLOSED - 5 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) - [Could I reach Ichkeul national park with public transportation?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45542/could-i-reach-ichkeul-national-park-with-public-transportation/45561#45561) - Vince
2. [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [How much extra time to allow in Dublin Airport for US pre-clearance?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45612/22140) - Mark Mayo
3. [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [To Apply for a visa: need "one-year health insurance" - but can only book insurance for 365 days](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45554/to-apply-for-a-visa-need-one-year-health-insurance-but-can-only-book-insura/45571#45571) - JoErNanO
4. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Applying for a B2 cohabitating visa with previous overstay as a minor](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45614/applying-for-a-b2-cohabitating-visa-with-previous-overstay-as-a-minor/45622#45622) - JoErNanO
5. [Rory Alsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop) - [Airport options for trip to Genoa and Verona](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45582/airport-options-for-trip-to-genoa-and-verona/45583#45583) - Mark Mayo

Answer (score 0):

### April 1st - CLOSED - 5 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) - [How to tell how bad touts are for a given country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44974/how-to-tell-how-bad-touts-are-for-a-given-country/45460#45460) - chx
2. [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [Chicago ORD Airport Hotels Shuttle Services and Transportation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45530/22140) - chx
3. [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [Travelling from the UK to Spain, have lost passport, any ideas?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45475/travelling-from-the-uk-to-spain-have-lost-passport-any-ideas/45479#45479) - Mark Mayo
4. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Misspelled middle name in passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45459/misspelled-middle-name-in-passport/45462#45462) - Dirty-flow
5. [Rory Alsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop) - [Where is exactly the place of Winterfell from Game of Thrones?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45538/1381) - Mark Mayo
6. [MeNoTalk](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/10051/menotalk) - [How to clean drug misdemeanor in US so I don't get stopped at border every time?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45547/how-to-clean-drug-misdemeanor-in-us-so-i-dont-get-stopped-at-border-every-time/45551#45551) - declined, both upvotes received after the day had finished (Mark Mayo)
7. [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception)

Comment: Are you going to try harder, this time? :P

Comment: @JoErNanO hopefully I won't be incapacitated for half a month again this time :D

Comment: @JoErNanO since I am banned from chat, I guess I can manage to join the April competition, only this time I will make sure to kick your ass ;)

Comment: @MeNoTalk Alright! :)

Comment: Wow. We need to find eight questions (cos the March one is still on) in 48 hours? That'll be tough...

Comment: @chx there are still like 60 unanswered questions, but yes, it's going to get tougher :) But that's the point, we've got them down from like 150 unanswered a few months ago.

Comment: @JoErNanO reminder it started 26 hours ago ;)

Comment: @MarkMayo Never forget the hare and the tortoise. :)

Comment: I had an answer with an upvote, I just didn't have time to add it here, I added it now, does that mean I am out?

Comment: @MeNoTalk not if the upvote was before the end of the day, I'll take a look

Comment: @MeNoTalk both upvotes were received today, not before the deadline :(

Comment: @MarkMayo ok :/

Comment: @menotalk You didn't even *try* man!

Comment: @JoErNanO see above - yes he did, he just got upvotes too late :/

Answer (score 0):

### April 5th - CLOSED - 5 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) - [Waiting for visa to be express mailed one day before international flight](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26717/waiting-for-visa-to-be-express-mailed-one-day-before-international-flight/45636#45636) - Vince
2. [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [What is the cheapest and fastest way of traveling between Liege and Paris with deterministic travelling times?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45689/22140) - Vince
3. [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [How long does it take for a UK Visa application in New Delhi?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45668/how-long-does-it-take-for-a-uk-visa-application-in-new-delhi/45684#45684) -
   JoErNanO
4. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Can we go outside from airport in India if we have connecting flights for USA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45633/can-we-go-outside-from-airport-in-india-if-we-have-connecting-flights-for-usa/45635) - Mark Mayo
5. [Rory Alsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop) - [Having a Skype (video/voice) in public in Paris](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/45688/1381) - JoErNanO

Answer (score 0):

### April 7th - CLOSED - 4 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) - [Surname and Given name swapped in new passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45568/surname-and-given-name-swapped-in-new-passport/45736#45736) - JoErNanO
2. [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [Safe parking in the centre of Mexico City](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/44552/22140) - Vince
3. [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [How to decline CDW and LDW when booking a car online?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45580/how-to-decline-cdw-and-ldw-when-booking-a-car-online/45746#45746) - Mark Mayo
4. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Airway companies that overbook flights, and those that don't overbook](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45713/airway-companies-that-overbook-flight-and-those-that-dont-overbook/45716) - Vince
5. [Rory Alsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop) -

Answer (score 0):

### April 9th - CLOSED - 3 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) - [Travelling to the UK as a South African citizen - evidence for funds?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45804/travelling-to-the-uk-as-a-south-african-citizen-evidence-for-funds/45817#45817) - Vince
2. [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) -
3. [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [Turkish Airlines Baggage Allowance](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45829/turkish-airlines-baggage-allowance/45846#45846) - Mark Mayo
4. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Getting from Dublin Airport to Dublin Ferryport by public transport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45807/getting-from-dublin-airport-to-dublin-ferryport-by-public-transport/45818?noredirect=1#comment86825_45818) - Mark Mayo

Answer (score 0):

### April 11th - CLOSED - 3 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) - [How cheaply can we eat in Ireland while still experiencing traditional Irish foods?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44933/how-cheaply-can-we-eat-in-ireland-while-still-experiencing-traditional-irish-foo/45990#45990) - chx
2. [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [Entering US from Canada by bus (VWP citizen)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45939/entering-us-from-canada-by-bus-vwp-citizen/45941#45941) - chx
3. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [ESTA US Application](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45951/esta-us-application/45957#45957) - Vince

Answer (score 0):

### April 13th - CLOSED - 3 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) - [Where can a tourist to Malta ride an articulated bus?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46038/where-can-a-tourist-to-malta-ride-an-articulated-bus/46044#46044) - Vince
2. [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [Prepaid SIM card in France with Free mobile](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46025/prepaid-sim-card-in-france-with-free-mobile/46027#46027) - chx
3. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Where is the official Iranian Railways website?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46022/where-is-the-official-iranian-railways-website/46023#46023) - Mark Mayo

Answer (score 0):

### April 17th - CLOSED - 3 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) - [Does my Australian friend need my passport and visa information if he buys my ticket?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46298/does-my-australian-friend-need-my-passport-and-visa-information-if-he-buys-my-ti/46299#46299) - Vince
2. [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [Can I stay in Zurich airport If I get there before my visa starts?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46177/can-i-stay-to-zurich-airport-if-i-reach-before-my-visa-starts/46279#46279) - Mark Mayo
3. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [If I use TSA Pre-Check, can I still enter security through the first class line?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46275/if-i-use-tsa-pre-check-can-i-still-enter-security-through-the-first-class-line/46276#46276) - Vince

Answer (score -1):

### April 15th - CLOSED - 3 contestants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) - [How long should I wait before applying for a visa after being refused entry?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46134/how-long-should-i-wait-before-applying-for-a-visa-after-being-refused-entry/46136#46136) - Vince
2. [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [JFK outbound International connection time (separate tickets and terminals)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43434/jfk-outbound-international-connection-time-separate-tickets-and-terminals/46168#46168) - Mark Mayo
3. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Meeting friends at Heathrow in transit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46180/meeting-friends-at-heathrow-in-transit/46183#46183) - Mark Mayo