# Travel.SE Competitions Leaderboard

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, fun, competitions

### Table

```
**Person   Competitions   Wins**

JoErNanO           6        3
Mark Mayo          5        1
Vince              5        1
mts                1        1
MeNoTalk           5        0
RoflcoptrException 3        0
chx                3        0
Quy                2        0
Relaxed            2        0
RoryAlsop          2        0
Gayot Fow          2        0
Willeke            2        0
nic                1        0
Daniil             1        0
```

### Future competitions

[October 2019 Old Question Answerathon! 1 contestant so far](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6330/89966)

### Active competitions

[September 2019 Old Question Answerathon! 4 contestants remain](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5268/89966)

[August 2019 Answerathon! 2 Participants left](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5189/august-2019-answerathon-entries-open-now?cb=1)

### Past competitions

[June 2016 - The Great 5 Year Anniversary Bounty Bonanza](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3689/the-great-5-year-anniversary-bounty-bonanza-closed-mts-won) - mts won

[December 2015 TravelExpats Winter Bash 2015](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3505/december-double-site-competition-around-hats) - JoErNanO won

[June 2015 - Graphical Answerathon](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/graphical-answerathon-2015-round-1-begins-on-the-15th-of-june-2015) - no winners

[May 2015 - Answerathon](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/may-answerathon) - Vince won

[April 2015 - Answerathon](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3081/april-answerathon-3-remain) - Mark Mayo won

[March 2015 - Answerathon](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3036/march-answerathon-winner-joernano) - JoErNanO won

[February 2015 - Answerathon](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3015/february-answerathon-last-man-standing-competition-joernano-won) - JoErNanO won

#### Competitions Explained

The answerathon competitions have required people to continually answer unanswered questions, AND get upvotes, every two days without missing. The last one standing wins.

Comment: I think this is kinda incomplete...

Comment: I would love it if someone adds all competitions that are now missing.

Comment: Mind adding the August 2019 Answerathon to the "active" list?

Comment: @gparyani it's SE - you can do it too :)

Comment: Don't have enough rep, and suggested edits aren't permitted on per-site metas. (I did edit the answer below since it's CW.)

Comment: @gparyani both are CW now, thanks for that!

Answer (score 9):

Our Hall of Fame for the [photo competitions](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5048/possible-topics-for-the-photo-competition).

| When | What | Most voted | Virtual prize |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| October 2018 | Travel Selfie | Mark Mayo | - |
| December 2018 | Buildings | Rory Alsop | Greg |
| January 2019 | Nature | mts | Sue |
| February 2019 | Water | mts | WedaPashi |
| March 2019 | Bus Stops | Tor-Einar Jarnbjo | hippietrail |
| April 2019 | Roadtrip | Dirty-flow | Hanky Panky |
| May 2019 | Staircases | Tor-Einar Jarnbjo | gmauch |
| June 2019 | Animals | choster | JJJ |
| July 2019 | Bridges | helm | JJJ |
| August 2019 | "Seen through a train window" | Willeke | - |
| September 2019 | Towers | Kuba | Tor-Einar Jarnbjo |
| October 2019 | Musical instruments | Tor-Einar Jarnbjo | - |
| November 2019 | "How did that happen?" | Mark Mayo | - |
| December 2019 | Winter public holidays | Chris H | - |
| January 2020 | Countries | Dirty-flow | - |
| February 2020 | Lighthouses | jason.kaisersmith | Dirty-flow |
| March 2020 | Travel Favorites | undefined | - |
| April 2020 | Hotels | mlc | Mark Mayo |
| May 2020 | Waterfalls | Chris H | - |
| June 2020 | Local Markets | undefined | - |
| July 2020 | Non-motorized vehicles | gparyani | Ray Butterworth |
| August 2020 | Mountains | Dirty-flow | Kuba |
| September 2020 | "Something small" | Kuba | Vince |
| October 2020 | "Impossible travel" | mlc | - |
| November 2020 | Nature/Wildlife | Mark Mayo | Chris H |
| December 2020 | Retired means of travel | Zach Lipton | PeterM |
| January 2021 | Best of Travel 2020 | Kuba & Bernhard (*tie*) | JJJ |
| February 2021 | "Close to home" | Madhu Bhat | jcklopp |
| March 2021 | Decorated walls | mlc | MattAllegro |
| April 2021 | [Trees](/questions/6939/april-2021-photo-competition-trees) | jcklopp | Mark Mayo |
| May 2021 | [Architecture](/questions/6978/may-2021-photo-competition-architecture) | Mark Mayo | undefined |
| June 2021 | [Castles and similar structures](/questions/7000/june-2021-photo-competition-castles-and-similar-structures) | undefined | MattAllegro |
| July 2021 | [Summer 2011 or earlier](/questions/7031/july-2021-photo-competition-ten-year-anniversary) | Willeke | Glorfindel |
| August 2021 | [Beaches](/questions/7058/august-2021-photo-competition-beaches) | undefined | JonathanReez |
| September 2021 | [Places](/questions/7108/september-2021-photo-competition-places-different-rules) | Rory Alsop | undefined |
| October 2021 | [Local parks](/questions/7136/october-2021-photo-competition-local-parks) | JJJ | mlc |
| November 2021 | [Photos gone wrong](/questions/7161/november-2021-photo-competition-photos-gone-wrong) | Kuba | Mark Mayo |
| December 2021 | [Places that no longer exist](/questions/7181/december-2021-photo-competition-places-buildings-scenes-that-no-longer-exist) | Xnero | - |
| January 2022 | [Water-based modes of transport](/questions/8205/january-2022-photo-competition-water-based-modes-of-transport) | Mark Mayo | - |
| February 2022 | [Foreign Food](/questions/8230/february-2022-photo-competition-foreign-food) | gparyani | Vince |
| March 2022 | [Unusual modes of transportation](/questions/8251/march-2022-photo-competition-unusual-modes-of-transportation) | Willeke | mlc |
| April 2022 | [Signs of change of season](/questions/8272/april-2022-photo-competition-signs-of-change-of-season) | mlc | jcklopp |
| May 2022 | [Doors, gates, and other portals](/questions/8284/may-2022-photo-competition-doors-gates-and-other-portals) | jcklopp | Rory Alsop |
| June 2022 | [Statues and other sculptures](/questions/8313/june-2022-photo-competition-statues-and-other-pieces-of-art-or-art-that-decor) | Willeke | mlc |
| July 2022 | [Purple](/questions/8341/july-2022-photo-competition-photos-highlighting-real-world-examples-natural-or) | Slartibartfast | jcklopp |
| August 2022 | [Things (far) out of place](/august-2022-photo-competition-things-far-out-of-place) | Weather Vane | ex-user3761894 |
| September 2022 | [3+ different forms of transport](/questions/8377/september-2022-photo-competition-photos-showing-three-or-more-different-forms-o) | jcklopp | Weather Vane |
| October 2022 | [Yellow](/october-2022-photo-competition-yellow) | Mark Mayo | Rory Alsop |
| November 2022 | [Lights](/questions/8409/november-2022-photo-competition-lights) | Mark Mayo | Greg Hewgill |
| December 2022 | [Borders](/questions/8422/december-2022-photo-competition-borders) | gmauch | Kuba |
| January 2023 | [New](/questions/8451/january-2023-photo-competition-new) | Greg Hewgill | jcklopp |
| February-March 2023 | [Renovated](/questions/8469/february-march-2023-photo-competition-renovated) | Willeke | Relaxed |
| April 2023 | [Fountains](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8484/april-2023-photo-competition-fountains) | jcklopp | MattAllegro |