# May answerathon - CLOSED - Vince won

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, fun, competitions

To give people time to enter, this will start on May 1st, UTC at midnight.

Rules: To stay in the competition, you must:

- answer an [unanswered question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered) not asked by you AND receive an upvote for your answer.
- **once the upvote has occurred (and not earlier)), edit the latest answer on this page for the date in question, and someone else can review and confirm.**
- IF there are no [unanswered questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered) at all (hah), then and only then can you answer a previously-answered question for your 'day'.
- IF the question you answer is marked as a duplicate on the same 'day', your answer is invalidated.
- IF the question you answered is put on hold by the community on the same 'day', your answer is invalidated.
- IF you are part of a previous ongoing Answerathon, and it's still going, you CANNOT use the same answer to enter more than one competition. You'll have to answer a new question for each.

Each 'day' will last for 48 hours.  So May 1st-2nd inclusive is a day, May 3rd-4th is a day, and so on.

Miss a 'day' and you're out.

*However, please - if we finally hit a day where you can't answer something with 
a proper answer, i.e. with a citation or evidence or something useful to the author, don't post a weak answer on a question.*

I'll provide the sample answer template below for  May 1st. If you intend to enter, put your name there now and prepare for battle :)

Comment: While the rules make sense for the site it makes the competition a lot harder just process wise. Oh well.

Comment: @chx Why so? Want to come to the tse chat and talk about it?

Comment: I think he means in terms of tracking. But in reality it's the same - just check at end of 'day' that they have upvotes and the question isn't closed.  All good.

Comment: Mark do not forget this ;) http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3003/competition-when-will-we-hit-11-111-questions

Comment: @IKeelYou indeed, but it's locked at present, I've asked Rofl to open it for us

Answer (score 3):

### May 9th - CLOSED - Vince won

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) -
2. [Vince](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [Day trip to castle(s) when staying in Bucharest](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47248/day-trip-to-castles-when-staying-in-bucharest/47380#47380) - JoErNanO

Answer (score 0):

### May 1st - OPEN - People can still register for the competition by adding an answer

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [Summer Sea Travel from Dubrovnik to Split](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/46420/22140) - Vince
2. [Vince](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [App where one can specify transit city](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46979/app-where-one-can-specify-transit-city/46985#46985) - JoErNanO
3. [Gayot Fow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow) - [Can I stay in UK after finishing my short English language courses?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/47019/22140) - JoErNanO
4. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke) - [Berlin to Göttingen by Train or Bus](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/47028/22140) - JoErNanO

Answer (score 0):

### May 3rd - OPEN - 4 entrants

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - 
   [Transfer from domestic flight to international flight in Nassau Airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/46558/22140) -Willeke
2. [Vince](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [As Philippine do I need a transit visa on a cruise through Schengen countries and the UK and Ireland?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43888/as-philippine-do-i-need-a-transit-visa-on-a-cruise-through-schengen-countries-an/47101#47101)  - Willeke
3. [Gayot Fow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow) -
4. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke) - [Is there secure bicycle parking at the Reading train station?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46567/is-there-secure-bicycle-parking-at-the-reading-train-station) - Vince

Answer (score 0):

### May 5th - OPEN - 3 survivors

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [Affordable and accessible accommodation options with car parking near Paris?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47135/affordable-and-accessible-stay-near-paris) - Vince
2. [Vince](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [Can I change our assigned seats on our TGV Atlantic train itinerary?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47144/can-i-change-our-assigned-seats-on-our-tgv-atlantic-train-itinerary/47164#47164) - JoErNanO
3. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke) -  <del>[What should be my expectations for airfare to France?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47230/what-should-be-my-expectations-for-airfare-to-france)</del>  - JoErNanO - Answer was closed as too broad during the competition day

Answer (score 0):

### May 7th - OPEN - 2 survivors

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [How reliable is the Cuban public transport network?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/47184/22140) - Vince
2. [Vince](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3044/vince) - [Use of scientific visa (schengen short stay scientist work visa issued by France) for tourism related travel to italy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47285/use-of-scientific-visa-schengen-short-stay-scientist-work-visa-issued-by-france/47289#47289) - JoErNanO