# Graphical Answerathon 2015 - Round 1 begins on the 15th of June 2015

Tags: discussion, fun, competitions

### Rules

#### Competition Rules

1. To stay in the competition, you must answer an [unanswered question](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3152/answerathon-leaderboard) not asked by you AND receive at least one upvote for your answer. For the purposes of this competition, an unanswered question is any question where no image has been previously submitted in an answer.
2. The answer must contain a picture, be it a photo, a diagram, a screenshot, a still-frame from a movie, a drawing, a painting, etc.
3. The pictures must be freely linkable, and necessarily respect the [usual StackExchange copyright rules](http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy). Most licenses allow them to be linkable.
4. The provenance of the pictures must be stated and linked-to, and the copyright (if any) should be rendered explicit
5. Alteration of an image by Photoshop or other software is forbidden.  Exceptionally, an image can be altered by software so long as every pixel is uniformly treated (as in resizing an image).  Of course diagrams, flowcharts, and other graphic representations composed entirely by the OP are exempt.
6. The image must be unused by other competitors.  If two competitors post the same image [FGITW (i.e. first one to post it)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18014/what-is-fgitw-and-scite-on-mso) wins.
7. Each competition will last for a full week i.e 168 hours, using the UTC+00:00 time, for start and end days, common to all StackExchange sites. Therefore June 15st-21nd inclusive is a week, June 22rd-28th is a week, and so on.
8. The competition re-starts at the end of each week, meaning that there are no elimination rounds. Hence everyone is welcome to participate during each week.

#### Answering Rules

1. Once the upvote has occurred (and not earlier)), edit the latest answer on this page for the date in question, and someone else can review and confirm.
2. IF there are no [unanswered questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered) at all (hah), then and only then can you answer a previously-answered question for your week.
3. IF the question you answer is marked as a duplicate on the same week, your answer is invalidated.
4. IF the question you answered is put on hold by the community on the same week, your answer is invalidated.
5. IF you are part of a previous ongoing Answerathon, and it's still going, you CANNOT use the same answer to enter more than one competition. You'll have to answer a new question for each.

*However, please - if we finally hit a week where you can't answer something with a proper answer, i.e. with a citation or evidence or something useful to the author, don't post a weak answer on a question.*

#### Scoring Rules

1. Competitors (and neutral observers) vote on the answer based upon its quality.  The image must be thematically precise, not just any crap image that appears in an image search.
   The image must lend weight to the answer. 
   For example: `Is it possible to visit the Parthenon at night?` An image that shows people roaming about the ruins at night wins. Upvote it. An image that shows the Parthenon lit up at night loses because it does not lend weight to the answer. Downvote it.  Unlike other competitions, this one has reputation risk to spice things up a bit.
2. Finally, competitors (and neutral observers) are required to acquit themselves of good sportsmanship and fair play. It might mean upvoting a better answer than yours.  It also means playing on if you get a downvote (no sulking!).

#### Formatting a picture

One way to include a picture is to use the `share` button of your source, if there is one.

On Stack Exchange, in posts, you can use the [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) syntax. So another way is to format picture using the following code, which includes [a caption-like text underneath the image, using `<sup>` tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255537/is-there-a-way-of-adding-some-caption-or-description-to-an-image):

```
![description, author, license](link to the original image) <br /><sup>*description, author, license*</sup>
```

For example:

```
![Mimosa Yellow butterfly - Pyrisitia nise larae syn. Eurema n. l., by Alan Hopkins, under CC BY-NC-ND 2.0](https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8853/17336008490_f4239a2814_m_d.jpg) <br /><sup>*Mimosa Yellow butterfly - Pyrisitia nise larae syn. Eurema n. l., by Alan Hopkins, under CC BY-NC-ND 2.0*</sup>
```

which renders as:

[image: Mimosa Yellow butterfly - Pyrisitia nise larae syn. Eurema n. l., by Alan Hopkins, under CC BY-NC-ND 2.0] 
<sup>*Mimosa Yellow butterfly - Pyrisitia nise larae syn. Eurema n. l., by Alan Hopkins, under CC BY-NC-ND 2.0*</sup>

Comment: "Alteration of an image by Photoshop or other software is forbidden. Exceptionally, an image can be altered by software so long as every pixel is uniformly treated (as in resizing an image)." - What if no suitable diagram exists, but I wish to create one? Or highlighting an area of an existing image (a map for example) would make the answer clearer? Do I have to do this all with a printout and a pen?

Comment: @CMaster, thanks for that comment.  Astute.  Rule amended

Answer (score 2):

## Round 1 - 15th to 21st June 2015 - OPEN

---

### Register by adding your name below

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) -
2. [Gayot Fow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow) - [Schengen visa refused from German embassy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49478/schengen-visa-refused-from-german-embassy/49498#49498)  and  [Optimal packing method for bras?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49825/optimal-packing-method-for-bras/49845#49845)
3. [RoflcoptrException](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/693/roflcoptrexception) -
4. [IKeelYou](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/10051/ikeelyou) -
5. [Vince](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3044) -