# December double site competition around hats!

Tags: discussion, fun, competitions, winter-bash

For those competitive, please simply edit the answer below when you want to 'enter' the competition.

It'll simply be: whoever gets the most combined numbers of hats on Travel.SE and on Expats.SE, in an effort to help both sites.

That is, if you have 7 on travel and 3 on expats, your total is 10.

Comment: That's cheating. Let's only make it on Travel.SE.. this is custom tailored competition :/

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis you don't have to participate, but as discussed in chat before the comp started, it's to try and help the expats site, our sister site.

Comment: and frankly, as seen below, @JoErNano is very close!

Comment: I'd love to help the site! but I do not like the idea of you winning in anything about hats ;)

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis well if you beat me, I can't win ;)

Comment: Let's do a network wide competition!

Comment: @RoflcoptrException bit late for that, but I suppose you can start another Q?

Answer (score 5):

[Link to Travel Winterbash leaderboard](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/travel.stackexchange.com).

[Link to Expats Winterbash leaderboard](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/expatriates.stackexchange.com).

Entrants in this dual competition, with travel, expats, and total hats thus far:

Rank, Name and Hats

1. JoErNanO: 29 + 16 = 45 hats
2. Heidel Ber Gensis: 35 + 9 = 44 hats
3. Mark Mayo: 25 + 8 = 33 hats

Comment: Hat trick!!!!!!!!!!!!