# The Great 5 Year Anniversary Bounty Bonanza - CLOSED - mts won

Tags: discussion, fun, competitions, bounties

## The Great 5 Year Anniversary Bonanza

Our 5 year anniversary falls on the 28th of June this year, if we consider our birth date to be [the date our public beta went live](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6591/travel). Time to celebrate this Travel.SE style - with a competition!

### Rules

For the whole month of June we will be running a bounty giveaway. **Users sign up and agree to place and keep three bounties live during the entire month.** In other words, each participant starts with three bounties on the 1st of June, and must end with three bounties on the 30th of June. Whenever a bounty is awarded or expire, it must be replaced by another bounty.

Mark created a [chat event for the Bonanza](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule). Participating users are advised to register for the event.

Each user adds an answer to this Meta post detailing which questions they have offered bounties on and the date (UTC). These will then be checked and validated by another user. The answer should look something like this:

> ### JoErNanO
>
> Total number of bounties: **1**
>
> - Date - Question link - Bounty value - Validated by
> - 1st June 2016 - [Doing stops on Italian regional trains. How long exactly is the ticket valid?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69316/doing-stops-on-italian-regional-trains-how-long-exactly-is-the-ticket-valid) - 100 - GayotFow

The answer should also be marked as community wiki to allow all users to validate the bounties (low reputation users can't edit non-community wiki answers without having to await review).

### Winners and Prizes

At the end of the competition, the winners will be forever honoured in our [hall of fame](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3152/22140). We will try to award some prizes, in the form of reputation. We might even be able to give away some swag items, but can't promise anything as of now since that depends on the SE higher-ups.

---

### Competition Tips

#### Finding a Bounty-Worthy Question

Not to worry. The final two weeks of May 2016 is for the "Great Flood of Bounty Worthy Questions", where we flood the site with incredibly wonderful questions that can be bountied. The winner of that mini-competition gets street-cred for creativity.

#### Still can't find any?

Not to worry.  Any question will do. Answered, unanswered, old, new, whatever... As long as it's a real question that is half-way decent, you can put a bounty on it to bring it more attention. Remember, the big objective here is to have a bounty bonanza that attracts lots of new people from other SO sites who see what's on and think, "...hey! I can pick up some rep over on Travel by collecting a few bounties...". Maybe they will, maybe they won't, but perhaps a few will go on to become great TSE companions.

#### Don't have rep to spare for bounties?

Not to worry. If you want to participate but are struggling with reputation, see "**finding a bounty worthy question**" above. You can jump in and help by  saving up some incredibly fascinating questions. Do you like to prospect for investment properties while travelling for leisure?  Do you like to go ice-fishing in the Hudson Bay? Are you looking for a place to go bead-begging when the Mardi Gras is over? Did you ever think about wind-surfing down the Danube? Why is there a golf club next to Nuuk airport? Which parts of the underground city in Verona are open to the public?  Put your thinking caps on!

---

### Current Participants

```
┌─────────────────────┬──────────┐
│       Person        │ Bounties │
├─────────────────────│──────────┤
│ mts                 │   24     │
│ CMaster             │   18     │
│ Vince               │   18     │
│ Gayot Fow           │   16     │
│ Mark Mayo           │   15     │
│ Willeke             │   15     │
│ Heidel Ber Gensis   │   14     │
│ chx                 │   13     │
│ JoErNanO            │   13     │
│ Berwyn              │    7     │
│ Zach Lipton         │    4     │
├─────────────────────│──────────┤
│ T O T A L           │   157    │
└─────────────────────┴──────────┘
```

---

**Reputation spent on bounties**

```
┌─────────────────────┬──────────┐
│       Person        │  Rep     │
├─────────────────────│──────────┤
│ CMaster             │   2600   │
│ mts                 │   2600   │
│ Gayot Fow           │   1900   │
│ Vince               │   1150   │
│ Heidel Ber Gensis   │   1150   │
│ JoErNanO            │   1100   │
│ Berwyn              │    850   │
│ Willeke             │    750   │
│ Mark Mayo           │    750   │
│ chx                 │    700   │
│ Zach Lipton         │    200   │
├─────────────────────│──────────┤
│ T O T A L           │  13750   │
└─────────────────────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: what exactly is the "validated by" for? we check if the bounties are really there as claimed? if so then I have validated your first three bounties correctly

Comment: @mts Exactly that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### mts

Total number of bounties: **24**

- **Date - Question link - Bounty value - Validated by**
- 30 June 2016 - [How do I minimize total cost of separate flights to the same destination plus optionally accommodation?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/13845/32134) - 100 - Tim Malone
- 30 June 2016 - [Uber/Didi to Badaling (八达岭) from Gulou (鼓楼) for sunrise?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/71982/32134) - 100 - Tim Malone
- 29 June 2016 - [Is the Han River in Seoul clean enough for kayaking?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/71934/32134) - 150 - Tim Malone
- 29 June 2016 - [Legally drive a Canadian car in Central and South America for extended periods?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/70906/32134) - 300 - Tim Malone
- 28 June 2016 - [What are the least crowded times to visit the Aquarium in Brooklyn, NYC?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/71267/32134) - 100 - JoErNanO
- 27 June 2016 - [Where can I find arrivals / departures timetables for Italian train stations online?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/72129/32134) - 50 - JoErNanO
- 27 June 2016 - [Finding local train ticket agents/offices in China.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/71969/32134) - 100 - JoErNanO
- 22 June 2016 - [How do I find the cheapest date to book a given hotel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/62745/32134) - 400 - Heidel Ber Gensis
- 21 June 2016 - [UK visa application - what visa type to select for a conference?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/71005/32134) - 100 - Heidel Ber Gensis
- 19 June 2016 - [Does the Vietnam Phu Quoc National Park allow visitors to camp on the grounds?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/65736/32134) - 100 - Tim Malone
- 19 June 2016 - [Contain the Georgian Triangle and Southwestern Ontario any 'drive-through' parks or wildlife areas?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/55496/32134) - 50 - Tim Malone
- 16 June 2016 - [Public transport access to Pyrenees (GR10)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/71202/32134) - 100 - Vince
- 16 June 2016 - [Child travel consent for Lima, Peru](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/63977/32134) - 150 - Vince
- 14 June 2016 - [Where can I go windsurfing or snorkeling in July in southern India?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/68830/32134) - 50 - blackbird57
- 12 June 2016 - [Can I travel by boat from the North Sea to the Mediterranean passing via Paris?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/70764/32134) - 100 - Heidel Ber Gensis
- 11 June 2016 - [Can I sign up in advance for a Joint Security Area tour that departs from Imjingak?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/65500/32134) - 100 - Vince
- 9 June 2016 - [How easy is it to park in Rimini in August?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/63826/32134) - 50 - Zach Lipton
- 8 June 2016 - [Printing a (scientific) poster near Boğaziçi University in Istanbul](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/70758/32134) - 50 - Heidel Ber Gensis
- 8 June 2016 - [Travelling from Bulgaria to UK via Turkey, will I have issues with tobacco products bought from the EU?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/61881/32134) - 100 - Heidel Ber Gensis
- 8 June 2016 - [Is it possible for China (PRC) passport holders to receive a Multiple Journey Visa (MJV) for Singapore?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/65366/32134) - 50 - Vince
- 3 June 2016 - [How to retrieve checked-through luggage if I don't board a connecting flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/63863/32134) - 150 - Vince
- 31st May 2016 - [Rock climbing when on Malta](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/25748/32134) - 50 - JoErNanO
- 31st May 2016 - [Do any Chinese embassies or consulates grant multiple-entry visas to people from a third country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/48052/32134) - 50 - JoErNanO
- 31st May 2016 - [Is it pretty easy for an American to get a Chinese visa in Hong Kong?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/11507/32134) - 50 - JoErNanO

Answer (score 8):

### Mark Mayo

Total number of bounties: **15**

- **Date - Question link - Bounty value - Validated by**
- June 1 - [Jersey City Journal Square PATH parking - how do I make a reservation?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67729/jersey-city-journal-square-path-parking-how-do-i-make-a-reservation) - 50 - mts
- June 1 - [From which point near the NSW/QLD border does it become legal for pedestrians to walk along the M1 (Pacific Highway)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66808/from-which-point-near-the-nsw-qld-border-does-it-become-legal-for-pedestrians-to) - 50 - mts
- June 1 - [How can I observe the 3rd Infantry Regiment at Arlington Cemetery during closing time?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69227/how-can-i-observe-the-3rd-infantry-regiment-at-arlington-cemetery-during-closing) - 50 - mts
- June 2 - [Where in Burlington, VT can I store luggage?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69020/where-in-burlington-vt-can-i-store-luggage) - 50 - Vince
- June 4 - [Where in Beyneu (Kazakhstan) can I get local money?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67255/where-in-beyneu-kazakhstan-can-i-get-local-money) - 50 - mts
- June 4 - [What are the options of getting from Beyneu to Aktau in Kazakhstan?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67251/what-are-the-options-of-getting-from-beyneu-to-aktau-in-kazakhstan) - 50 - mts
- June 5 - [How fast is the mobile network (3G) in Myanmar (in February 2016)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64387/how-fast-is-the-mobile-network-3g-in-myanmar-in-february-2016) - 50 - CMaster
- June 8 - [What are the mountains visible in these photos?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66348/what-are-the-mountains-visible-in-these-photos) - 50 - Vince
- June 8 - [New US passport hasn't arrived in over 10 weeks. What to do next?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67645/new-us-passport-hasnt-arrived-in-over-10-weeks-what-to-do-next) - 50 - Vince
- June 21 - [Is it possible to enter Belgium without a return ticket?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69548/is-it-possible-to-enter-belgium-without-a-return-ticket) - 50 - Heidel Ber Gensis
- June 21 - [Two different workshops in one J-1 visa period](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71115/two-different-workshops-in-one-j-1-visa-period) - 50 - Heidel Ber Gensis
- June 21 - [Will my American Xbox work in China?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67749/will-my-american-xbox-work-in-china) - 50 - Heidel Ber Gensis
- June 28 - [Can I leave South Korea to reset the 90 days visa counter?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64193/can-i-leave-south-korea-to-reset-the-90-days-visa-counter) - 50 - JoErNaNO
- June 28 - [As an Indian citizen, can I apply and have both a B1 and F1 visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68558/as-an-indian-citizen-can-i-apply-and-have-both-a-b1-and-f1-visa) - 50 - JoErNaNO
- June 30 - [Can you travel to Canada if banned from the USA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72328/can-you-travel-to-canada-if-banned-from-the-usa) - 50 - JoErNaNO

Comment: All that rep, but bounties of only 50?

Comment: Shrug, [if we're counting](http://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo?tab=bounties&sort=offered&page=1) ;)

Comment: UTC time people.. UTC ;)

Answer (score 7):

### Vince

Total number of bounties: **18**

- **Date - Question link - Bounty value - Validated by**
- 31st of May - [Palazzo Strozzi - is the online ticket queue shorter?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68633/palazzo-strozzi-is-the-online-ticket-queue-shorter) - 50 - mts
- 31st of May - [How can I use Global Entry lanes at Canadian airports if I don't have the physical Global Entry card?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68398/how-can-i-use-global-entry-lanes-at-canadian-airports-if-i-dont-have-the-physic) - 50 - mts
- 31st of May - [Baggage locker in downtown San Francisco](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68255/baggage-locker-in-downtown-san-francisco) - 50 - mts
- 3rd of June - [Which Schengen countries have bilateral agreements which ignore the standard 90/180 rule?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69255/which-schengen-countries-have-bilateral-agreements-which-allow-for-citizens-of-c) - 100 - CMaster
- 3rd of June - [London-Paris, Time Critical Agenda for the Louvre and Rodin Museum](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69211/london-paris-time-critical-agenda-for-the-louvre-and-rodin-museum) - 50 - CMaster
- 5th of June - [Visa-free stays involving paid activity in the Schengen Area - how do they work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69253/visa-free-stays-involving-paid-activity-in-the-schengen-area-how-do-they-work) - 50 - CMaster
- 8th of June - [Are there any Squat houses in Paris?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68809/are-there-any-squat-houses-in-paris) - 50 - Heidel Ber Gensis
- 10th of June - [Is it mandatory to show the debit card used for payment while checking in on Air India flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69081/is-it-mandatory-to-show-debit-card-while-checking-in-on-air-india-flights) - 50 - blackbird57
- 11th of June - [What does ticket status RLWL2/RAC4 mean on Indian Railways tickets?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68969/what-does-the-ticket-status-rlwl2-rac4-means-on-india-railways-tickets) - 50 - Heidel Ber Gensis
- 16th of June - [Who pays for transit between airports when connecting from PVG to SHA with China Eastern?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71354/who-pays-for-transit-between-airports-when-the-connecting-flight-is-from-another) - 100 - Heidel Ber Gensis
- 17th of June - [Chiang Saen to Jinghong by boat?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71236/chiang-saen-to-jinghong-by-boat) - 50 - Heidel Ber Gensis
- 17th of June - [What should be done before returning a rental caravan back to the rental company?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66064/what-should-be-done-before-returning-a-rental-caravan-back-to-the-rental-company) - 50 - Heidel Ber Gensis
- 22nd of June - [Can a Chinese citizen get Canadian visa in the USA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71220/can-a-chinese-citizen-get-canadian-visa-in-the-usa) - 50 - mts
- 22nd of June - [What campsites exist between Gaborone and Windhoek?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68618/what-campsites-exist-between-gaborone-and-windhoek) - 50 - mts
- 27th of June - [Haven't used a 5-year US B1/B2 visa for 4 years. Can I still enter the US with it?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71585/havent-used-a-5-year-us-b1-b2-visa-for-4-years-can-i-still-fly-to-the-us) - 50 - JoErNanO
- 27th of June - [Visiting Rio de Janeiro, Brazil as a volunteer for the 2016 Olympics what funds do I need for a visa, and in what form?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71116/visit-to-rio-2016-olympics-as-a-volunteer) - 50  - JoErNanO
- 27th of June - [Does insurance for expensive Items in checked luggage exist?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71813/does-insurance-for-expensive-items-in-checked-luggage-exist) - 150 - JoErNanO
- 30th of June - [Where can I find the e-ticket number of a previously flown Turkish Airlines flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71453/where-can-i-find-the-e-ticket-number-of-a-previously-flown-turkish-airlines-flig) - 100 - Tim Malone

Answer (score 7):

### CMaster

Total number of bounties: **18**

- **Date - Question link - Bounty value - Validated by**
- 1 June - [Is it easier for a westerner to obtain a Chinese tourist visa in Kazakhstan or Kyrgyzstan?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52778/is-it-easier-for-a-westerner-to-obtain-a-chinese-tourist-visa-in-kazakhstan-or-k) - 100 - JoErNanO
- 1 June - [Making pen and ink corrections on a UK visa form?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68868/making-pen-and-ink-corrections-on-a-uk-visa-form) - 100 - JoErNanO
- 1 June - [Do I still need a blood test for a Kurdistan residency permit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42664/do-i-still-need-a-blood-test-for-a-kurdistan-residency-permit) - 250 - JoErNanO
- 2 June - [Where in England can I walk on a high tension grid?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68525/where-in-england-can-i-walk-on-a-high-tension-grid) - 100 - Vince
- 4 June - [How to tell if travel location is "affordable"?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69488/how-to-tell-if-travel-location-is-affordable) - 100 - Vince
- 6 June - [Where can I hike in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69526/where-can-i-hike-in-the-uk) - 150 - Vince
- 9 June - [Where to buy/top up public transport tickets in Lisbon?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/70811/where-to-buy-top-up-public-transport-tickets-in-lisbon) - 100 - Heidel Ber Gensis
- 12 June - [My hands were scanned by a strange device during a security check at the airport. What was the purpose?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/70810/my-hands-were-scanned-by-a-strange-device-during-a-security-check-at-the-airport) - 100 - Heidel Ber Gensis
- 16 June - [Do any hotel chains do something like a Europe Pass? Like the Eurail pass, but for hotels](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68316/do-any-hotel-chains-do-something-like-a-europe-pass-like-the-eurail-pass-but-f) - 100 - ince
- 16 June - [Highest point in NYC that may be reached for free?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71211/highest-point-in-nyc-that-may-be-reached-for-free) - 100 - Vince
- 18 June - [Are there sites to find simcard options that cover more than just one country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/70867/are-there-sites-to-find-the-cheapest-or-best-simcard-options-that-cover-more-tha) - 100 - Heidel Ber Gensis
- 23 June - [How long does it take to get US from South Korea by Container Ship?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59473/how-long-does-it-take-to-get-us-from-south-korea-by-container-ship/) - 100 - JoErNanO
- 27 June - [Which Oyster card should I get as a foreign visitor to London?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67052/which-oyster-card-should-i-get-as-a-foreign-visitor-to-london) - 100 - Vince
- 27 June -  [Online tool to find points of interest along a route](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67955/online-tool-to-find-points-of-interest-along-a-route) - 150 - Vince
- 27 June - [Transfer from Washington National (DCA) to Washington Dulles(IAD)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57735/transfer-from-washington-national-dca-to-washington-dullesiad) - 100 - Vince
- 29 June - [Does a "Visa on Departure" exist?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66485/does-a-visa-on-departure-exist) - 200 - Zach Lipton
- 30 June - [Where on Ko Samui can I find a clean, non-tourist beach?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62361/where-on-ko-samui-can-i-find-a-clean-non-tourist-beach) - 150 - Zach Lipton
- 30 June - [UK last train cancellation and unhelpful staff - what to do?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71725/uk-last-train-cancellation-and-unhelpful-staff-what-to-do) - 500 - Tim Malone

Answer (score 6):

### JoErNanO

Total number of bounties: **13**

- **Date - Question link - Bounty value - Validated by**
- 30 June - [Are there red light districts in St. Petersburg or Moscow?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72295/are-there-red-light-districts-in-st-petersburg-or-moscow) - 500 - CMaster
- 27 June - [Where in Sweden can I celebrate midsommar with the locals?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71899/where-in-sweden-can-i-celebrate-midsommar-with-the-locals) - 50 - Vince
- 21 June - [Can I import a drone into Argentina?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71546/can-i-take-a-drone-on-a-plane-into-argentina) - 50 - mts
- 21 June - [How to apply for a Belarus tourist visa without booking a hotel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64577/how-to-apply-for-a-belarus-tourist-visa-without-booking-a-hotel) - 50 - mts
- 17 June - [Visiting Rio de Janeiro, Brazil as a volunteer for the 2016 Olympics what funds do I need for a visa, and in what form?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71116/visit-to-rio-2016-olympics-as-a-volunteer) - 50 - Vince
- 13 June - [How to improve the chances of getting a free ticket from a "Blue Girl" at the Bayreuth Festival?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69212/how-to-improve-the-chances-of-getting-a-free-ticket-from-a-blue-girl-at-the-ba) - 50 - Vince
- 13 June - [Can I demand my passport back in the middle of an application for a Chinese Visa in the UK?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/70929/can-i-demand-my-passport-back-in-the-middle-of-an-application-for-a-chinese-visa) - 50 - Vince
- 13 June - [What are the options of getting from Beyneu to Aktau in Kazakhstan?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67251/what-are-the-options-of-getting-from-beyneu-to-aktau-in-kazakhstan) - 50 - Vince
- 6 June - [Why does immigration check passports at some Schengen-only terminals?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68323/why-does-immigration-check-passports-at-some-schengen-only-terminals) - 50 - Vince
- 6 June - [Are Australian citizens now or in the very near future about to get ten year visas for China?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69617/are-australian-citizens-now-or-in-the-very-near-future-about-to-get-ten-year-vis) - 50 - Vince
- 1 June - [Visa Issues when crossing the English Channel by Jet Ski](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69220/visa-issues-when-crossing-the-english-channel-by-jet-ski) - 50 - mts
- 1 June - [Do non-CIS nationals have issues with visa checks on the Moscow-Dushanbe train?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67443/do-non-cis-nationals-have-issues-with-visa-checks-on-the-moscow-dushanbe-train) - 50 - mts
- 1 June - [Applying for a Schengen visa as a tourist in Romania?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/58975/applying-for-a-schengen-visa-as-a-tourist-in-romania) - 50 - mts

Answer (score 6):

### chx

Total number of bounties: **13**

- **Date - Question link - Bounty value - Validated by**
- 1 June [I am a US/UK citizen and I entered the UK with my US passport. Can I stay in the UK past the visa expiration date?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/58181/i-am-a-us-uk-citizen-and-i-entered-the-uk-with-my-us-passport-can-i-stay-in-the) - 50 - JoErNanO
- 1 June [Where can I find details on the level of difficulty of ATV/4x4 trails in Ontario, Canada?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56949/where-can-i-find-details-on-the-level-of-difficulty-of-atv-4x4-trails-in-ontario) - 50 - JoErNanO
- 1 June [Where in Chengdu can we see Sanxingdui artifacts, besides the museum in Guanghan?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51421/where-in-chengdu-can-we-see-sanxingdui-artifacts-besides-the-museum-in-guanghan) - 50 - JoErNanO
- 2 June [Overstayed in the US by 4 months and was later refused a B2 visa. How do I increase the chances of succeeding on my next try?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52766/overstayed-in-the-us-by-4-months-and-was-later-refused-a-b2-visa-how-do-i-incre) - 50 - Vince
- 6 June [Can I apply for a US tourist visa without holding a job, if my husband is employed?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62125/can-i-apply-for-a-us-tourist-visa-without-holding-a-job-if-my-husband-is-employ) - 50 - Vince
- 6 June [Where on Ko Samui can I find a clean, non-tourist beach?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62361/where-on-ko-samui-can-i-find-a-clean-non-touristic-beach) - 50 - Vince
- 7 June [For which countries does tourist visa apply after the end of a long-stay visa in Schengen countries?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53611/for-which-countries-does-tourist-visa-apply-after-the-end-of-a-long-stay-visa-in) - 100 - Vince
- 15 June [Where can I buy a souvenir stamp while traveling in European cities?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62735/where-can-i-buy-a-souvenir-stamp-while-traveling-in-european-cities) - 50 - Heidel Ber Gensis
- 15 June [Can I travel to Dublin with a Permanent Residence (UK)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62706/can-i-travel-to-dublin-with-a-permanent-residence-uk) - 50 - Heidel Ber Gensis
- 15 June [Parking in Venice in August - should I book a parking lot?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62643/parking-in-venice-in-august-should-i-book-a-parking-lot) - 50 - Heidel Ber Gensis
- 24 June [Traveling from NZ to USA, how much money do I need for CBP to let me in?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71260/traveling-to-usa-from-nz-how-much-money-do-i-need-for-cbp-to-let-me-in) - 50 - Vince
- 24 June [Can I apply for a Schengen visa for an earlier period than my existing one?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67103/can-i-apply-for-a-schengen-visa-for-an-earlier-period-than-my-existing-one) - 50 - Vince
- 24 June [Where I can find a guide in Peru to take me safely to the Jivaro headhunting tribe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66865/where-i-can-find-a-guide-in-peru-to-take-me-safely-to-the-jivaro-headhunting-tri) - 50 - Vince

Answer (score 6):

### Willeke

Total number of bounties: **15**

- **Date - Question link - Bounty value - Validated by**
- 31st May 2016 - [Is there a website to find points to get tap water at airports?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/61412/32134) - 50 - JoErNanO
- 31st May 2016 - [Priceline bidding: how does it work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/65807/32134) - 50 - JoErNanO
- 31st May 2016 - [Are there any non-obvious differentiators in travel-insurance policies?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/68802/32134) - 50 - JoErNanO
- 2nd June 2016 - [Inexpensive vehicular guided tour of Sydney](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/55708/inexpensive-vehicular-guided-tour-of-sydney) - 50 - Vince
- 6th June 2016 - [Is there a website or resource that lists what you can do in a given geographical area for free or almost for free?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27509/is-there-a-website-or-resource-that-lists-what-you-can-do-in-a-given-geographica) - 50 - Vince
- 6th June 2016 - [Can you rely on local tourist information centres to find accommodation in the summer in the Czech republic?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27516/can-you-rely-on-local-tourist-information-centres-to-find-accommodation-in-the-s) - 50 - Vince
- 9th June 2016 - [Are there sites to find the cheapest or best simcard options that cover more than just one country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/70867/are-there-sites-to-find-the-cheapest-or-best-simcard-options-that-cover-more-tha) - 50 - mts
- 12th June - [Can I obtain more than one working holiday visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13823/can-i-obtain-more-than-one-working-holiday-visa) - 50 - JoErNanO
- 14th June - [Is there a ship of the line that I can sail on from Britain?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/is-there-a-ship-of-the-line-that-i-can-sail-on-in-britain) - 50 - JoErNanO
- 19th June - [How can I bring a broken tablet on an airplane to the US?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38004/how-can-i-bring-a-broken-tablet-on-an-airplane-to-the-us) 50 - JoErNanO
- 20th June - [Should I expect þingvellir to be snowcovered early May?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46201/should-i-expect-%C3%BEingvellir-to-be-snowcovered-early-may) - 50 - mts
- 20th June - [Is there a city in the world with more bridges than Amsterdam, the Netherlands?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71682/is-there-a-city-in-the-world-with-more-bridges-than-amsterdam-the-netherlands) - 50 - mts
- 25th June - [When travelling from London to northern Sweden by train, is it possible to have a day of free sightseeing at anywhere other than Copenhagen?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1507/when-travelling-from-london-to-northern-sweden-by-train-is-it-possible-to-have) - 50 - mts
- 26th June - [As we are all adults here, how do I politely indicate that I need the toilet?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71728/as-we-are-all-adults-here-how-do-i-politely-indicate-that-i-need-the-toilet) - 50 - mts
- 29th June - [Practical food to take on flight without anything served?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44451/practical-food-to-take-on-flight-without-anything-served) - 50 - mts

Answer (score 6):

### Zach Lipton

Total number of bounties: **4**

- **Date - Question link - Bounty value - Validated by**
- 2 June [Does Global Entry help when entering the US by bus or train?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69038/does-global-entry-help-when-entering-the-us-by-bus-or-train) - 50 - Vince
- 6 June [Everest Base Camp Hiking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4846/everest-base-camp-hiking-) - 50 - Vince
- 12 June [Legally drive a Canadian car in Central and South America for extended periods?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/70906/can-one-drive-a-canadian-car-in-central-and-south-america-for-extended-periods) - 50 - Vince
- 28 June [Are there any luggage lockers in Ho Chi Minh City?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67973/are-there-any-luggage-lockers-in-ho-chi-minh-city) - 50 - Willeke

Answer (score 6):

### Heidel Ber Gensis

Total number of bounties: **14**

- **Date - Question link - Bounty value - Validated by**
- 02.JUN - [Availability and attitudes towards sky .........](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/61633/availability-and-attitudes-towards-sky-burial-tourism) - 50 - mts *
- 02.JUN - [Is it possible to trek from Zero Point to .......](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62543/is-it-possible-to-trek-from-zero-point-to-gurudongmar-lake-via-donkiala-pass-and) - 50 - mts *
- 09.JUN - [Do any Chinese embassies or consulates .](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48052/do-any-chinese-embassies-or-consulates-grant-multiple-entry-visas-to-people-from) - 50 - mts
- 09.JUN - [Business visa validity after I switch ............](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/70821/business-visa-validity-after-i-switch-organization) - 50 - mts *
- 09.JUN - [Looking for a two-level bridge somewhere .](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/65654/looking-for-a-two-level-bridge-somewhere-near-xanthi-greece) - 50 - mts *
- 12.JUN - [Do non-CIS nationals have issues with ......](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67443/do-non-cis-nationals-have-issues-with-visa-checks-on-the-moscow-dushanbe-train) - 50 - Vince
- 14.JUN - [Is the Berlin Wall Section on the ................](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69660/is-the-berlin-wall-section-on-the-sakharov-grounds-accessible-at-night) - 50 - Vince
- 17.JUN - [Buying photographic equipment in Taipe....](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/63806/buying-photographic-equipment-in-taipei) - 50 - Vince *
- 20.JUN - [Can one Drive a Canadian Car in Central ..](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/70906/can-one-drive-a-canadian-car-in-central-and-south-america-for-extended-periods) - 50 - mts
- 21.JUN - [Driving from Bucharest to Balchik ...............](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71730/driving-from-bucharest-to-balchik) - 50 - mts
- 22.JUN - [Is my Finnish Schengen residence permit ..](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69454/is-my-finnish-schengen-residence-permit-issued-for-work-still-valid-if-im-no) - 50 - mts *
- 28.JUN - [Laptop with no battery at Abu Dhabi ...........](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71916/laptop-with-no-battery-at-abu-dhabi-airport-security-check) - 50 - JoErNanO
- 29.JUN - [Free transfer between airports in same city.](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71906/free-transfer-between-airports-in-same-city) - 50 - CMaster
- 30.JUN -  
  [How to avoid toddlers on a long-distance ...](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69053/how-to-avoid-toddlers-on-a-long-distance-plane-flight) - 500 - CMaster *

---

<sup>* Awarded</sup>

Answer (score 5):

### Gayot

Total number of bounties: **16** for 1,900 points total

- **Date - Question link - Bounty value - Validated by**
- 30 June -
  [Is the Berlin Wall Section on the Sakharov Grounds Accessible at Night?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69660/is-the-berlin-wall-section-on-the-sakharov-grounds-accessible-at-night)
  500 - mts
- 28 June -
  [Does Siesta time in Panama affect business travelers?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71441/does-siesta-time-in-panama-affect-business-travelers) - 50 - mts
- 26 June -
  [Recreating Hemingway's Trip to Pamplona (Part 1)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72019/recreating-hemingways-trip-to-pamplona-part-1)
  50 - CMaster
- 25 June -
  [Finding Undisclosed Restaurants on the Adriatic Coast](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71219/finding-undisclosed-restaurants-on-the-adriatic-coast)
  100 - CMaster
- 22 June -
  [How to improve the chances of getting a free ticket from a "Blue Girl" at the Bayreuth Festival?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69212/how-to-improve-the-chances-of-getting-a-free-ticket-from-a-blue-girl-at-the-ba)
  100 - Heidel Ber Gensis
- 16 June -
  [Encountering Weasels in the Wild in Scotland](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/encountering-weasels-in-the-wild-in-scotland) - 50 - Tim Malone
- 15 June -
  [Free access to Venice museums for the disabled, but with parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69651/free-access-to-venice-museums-for-the-disabled-but-with-parking) - 50 - Tim Malone
- 14 June -  [Following in the Footsteps of Hemingway in Italy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69218/following-in-the-footsteps-of-hemingway-in-italy) - 100 (2nd) - Tim Malone
- 10 June -
  [Visa Issues when crossing the English Channel by Jet Ski](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69220/visa-issues-when-crossing-the-english-channel-by-jet-ski) - 50 - Tim Malone (awarded)
- 8 June -
  [What should a sponsor tell the ECO?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69228/what-should-a-sponsor-tell-the-eco)
  100 - Vince
- 6 June -
  [Is It OK to enter ancient and deserted chapels in the Russian countryside](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69221/is-it-ok-to-enter-ancient-and-deserted-chapels-in-the-russian-countryside) - 50 - Vince
- 6 June -
  [Following in the Footsteps of Hemingway in Italy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69218/following-in-the-footsteps-of-hemingway-in-italy) - 50 - Vince
- 2 June -
  [How can a tourist obtain an 'authentic' duelling scar?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69224/how-can-a-tourist-obtain-an-authentic-duelling-scar) - 500 - mts
- 1 June - [On the trail of the Alpine Ibex in Switzerland](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68157/on-the-trail-of-the-alpine-ibex-in-switzerland) - 50 - mts
- 1 June - [Travelling to Latin America to take hallucinogenic drugs: how does one do it safely?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67567/travelling-to-latin-america-to-take-hallucinogenic-drugs-how-does-one-do-it-saf) - 50 - mts
- 1 June - [Where can a tourist play horseshoes in Washington, DC?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67590/where-can-a-tourist-play-horseshoes-in-washington-dc) - 50 - mts (awarded)

Answer (score 5):

### Berwyn

Total number of bounties: **7**

- **Date - Question link - Bounty value - Validated by**
- 02-Jun-2016
  [Why is airline baggage measured in linear inches and not cubic volume?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68717/why-is-airline-baggage-measured-in-linear-inches) - 100 - mts
- 09-Jun-2016 [Can chartering a private plane be an affordable alternative to scheduled flights?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6283/can-chartering-a-private-plane-be-an-affordable-alternative-to-scheduled-flights) - 50 - mts
- 09-Jun-2016 [Do I need a boat license and can I get it in Australia to rent and drive boat in Europe?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/60032/do-i-need-a-boat-license-and-can-i-get-it-in-australia-to-rent-and-drive-boat-in) - 50 - mts
- 20-Jun 2016 [Whilst on ESTA I was stamped a 6 month B2 visa, would this be considered overstaying?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66696/whilst-on-esta-i-was-stamped-a-6-month-b2-visa-would-this-be-considered-oversta) - 50 - Tim Malone
- 20-Jun 2016 [Does Siesta time in Panama affect business travelers?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71441/does-siesta-time-in-panama-affect-business-travelers) - 50 - mts
- 20-Jun 2016 [Where can I find the e-ticket number of a previously flown Turkish Airlines flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/71453/where-can-i-find-the-e-ticket-number-of-a-previously-flown-turkish-airlines-flig) - 50 - mts
- 30-Jun 2016 [How can I see all routes flown by a given airline?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72195/how-can-i-see-all-routes-flown-by-a-given-airline) - 500 - Tim Malone