# Bounty Bonanza impact

Tags: discussion, fun, events, statistics

First, Congrats to [@mts](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32134/mts) who won the [5 Year Bounty Bonanza](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3689/the-great-5-year-anniversary-bounty-bonanza) with 24 offered bounties. And congrats to all who gave a grand total of 157 bounties in June.

Here I added some stats (from data.SE) on the site showing the increase in participation on  the month of June, please add/edit some stats as you find it useful.

First, [the number of bounties](http://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/7672/bounties-and-questions-by-month) has obviously increased in June, 127 accounted (I think data.SE is not yet up-to-date with yesterday's new bounties though) compared to previous months' average 27 offered bounties. And the total of rewards amounts to over 7000 points (compared to previous months' average 1000 points)

Second, [the number of answers increased by about 50%](http://data.stackexchange.com/travel/query/6134/total-questions-and-answers-per-month-for-the-last-12). After the average of 700-750 answers per month in 2016, June saw over 1100 posted answers.

Comment: TLDR: **Travel.SE is awesome.**

Comment: wowِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِِ

Comment: Thanks Vince, great stats and great META post.  Big big group hugs to everybody who played!

Answer (score 10):

According to the [site analytics](https://travel.stackexchange.com/site-analytics), there's an improvement in the following areas:

1. Upvotes: **~50% increase in upvotes compared to May, 2016**, while in May it increased ~10% only compared to April:

[image]

2. Accepted Answers: **30% increase in accepting answers (the tick) compared to May, 2016**. The increase from April to May, 2016 was so little, mainly due the May being 31 days.
3. A notable increase in the site traffic per day, which seems more than the normal expected monthly increase:

[image]

Comment: FYI Only 25k+ rep users can see the analytics.

Comment: @JoErNanO 25k+ users only.. that's why I posted the summary here..

Comment: Yup you are right. I added the comment to explain to the <25k rep users clicking the link why they can't see anything. :)

Comment: @JoErNanO You are a show off.. pizza man ;)

Comment: That's it. I'm downvoting you. :P

Comment: Are you accounting for June being a heavier travel month (and so presumably heavier question month) in the northern hemisphere?

Answer (score 7):

Bounty bonanza was great fun and a nice experience. Happy to be in for the next one.

I wanted to share some impressions of mine about the bonanza in random order

- we had a huge impact especially in the beginning. As can be seen in the plot in the A of @HeidelBerGensis traffic peaked over the first 2-3 weeks and I remember we had up to 10 Travel SE questions in the hot questions list when the bonanza kicked off
- the effect of bounties waned, while in the beginning 50rep bounties attracted good answers and lots of attention, by the end I had to beg for answers on a 400rep bounty.
- many of us were frustrated because bounties went to waste as nobody came along to answer. that led to increased placing of bounties to award existing answers instead of on unsolved questions.
- I have the impression that we got a few new users, but not necessarily related to the bonanza
- bounties barely attracted votes and traffic, many posts I bountied had only ca. 10 views more a day after and the answers that I awarded bounties to had as little as 2 upvotes (including mine). that's miserably voting performance of ours IMHO.
- many of the answers came from our circle of regulars

Comment: We had new users at the beginning. They stayed to get easy rep at the beginning of the competition and slowly their interest faded away.