# The 2018 Easter Bounty Bonanza!

Tags: discussion, fun, competitions, bounties

## The 2018 Easter Bounty Bonanza

### Rules

For the whole month of April we will be running a bounty giveaway. **Users sign up and agree to place and keep three bounties live during the entire month.** In other words, each participant starts with three bounties on the 1st of April, and must end with three bounties on the 30th of April. Whenever a bounty is awarded or expire, it must be replaced by another bounty.

Mark created a [chat event for the Bonanza](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule). Participating users are advised to register for the event.

Each user adds an answer to this Meta post detailing which questions they have offered bounties on and the date (UTC). These will then be checked and validated by another user. The answer should look something like this:

> ### JoErNanO
>
> Total number of bounties: **1**
>
> - Date - Question link - Bounty value - Validated by
> - 1st April 2018 - [Doing stops on Italian regional trains. How long exactly is the ticket valid?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69316/doing-stops-on-italian-regional-trains-how-long-exactly-is-the-ticket-valid) - 100 - Mark Mayo

The answer should also be marked as community wiki to allow all users to validate the bounties (low reputation users can't edit non-community wiki answers without having to await review).

### Winners and Prizes

At the end of the competition, the winners will be forever honoured in our [hall of fame](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3152/22140). Mark will give a bonus of 1000 rep to the winner.

---

### Competition Tips

#### Finding a Bounty-Worthy Question

Not to worry. [The final day of March 2018](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule) is for the "Great Flood of Bounty Worthy Questions", where we flood the site with incredibly wonderful questions that can be bountied. The winner of that mini-competition gets street-cred for creativity. Register [on the event for that](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule) as well!

#### Still can't find any?

Not to worry.  Any question will do. Answered, unanswered, old, new, whatever... As long as it's a real question that is half-way decent, you can put a bounty on it to bring it more attention. Remember, the big objective here is to have a bounty bonanza that attracts lots of new people from other SO sites who see what's on and think, "...hey! I can pick up some rep over on Travel by collecting a few bounties...". Maybe they will, maybe they won't, but perhaps a few will go on to become great TSE companions.

#### Don't have rep to spare for bounties?

Not to worry. If you want to participate but are struggling with reputation, see "**finding a bounty worthy question**" above. You can jump in and help by  saving up some incredibly fascinating questions. Do you like to prospect for investment properties while travelling for leisure?  Do you like to go ice-fishing in the Hudson Bay? Are you looking for a place to go bead-begging when the Mardi Gras is over? Did you ever think about wind-surfing down the Danube? Why is there a golf club next to Nuuk airport? Which parts of the underground city in Verona are open to the public?  Put your thinking caps on!

---

### Current Participants

```
┌──────────────────────────┬──────────┐
│       Person             │ Bounties │
├──────────────────────────│──────────┤
│ Mark Mayo                │   3      │
│ JonathanReez             │   5      │
│ Roddy Of The Frozen Peas │   3      │
├──────────────────────────│──────────┤
│ T O T A L                │   11     │
└──────────────────────────┴──────────┘
```

---

**Reputation spent on bounties**

```
┌──────────────────────────┬──────────┐
│       Person             │  Rep     │
├──────────────────────────│──────────┤
│ Mark Mayo                │   250    │
│ JonathanReez             │   500    │
│ Roddy Of The Frozen Peas │   150    │
├──────────────────────────│──────────┤
│ T O T A L                │   900    │
└──────────────────────────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: Is this working, do y'all think? I mean, none of my bounties have attracted any attention yet -- looks like only Jonathan's gotten any sort of responses.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas to be fair, thinking back to last time, it's sometimes about bountying the easily-answerable ones. Certainly our stats last time were higher. Give it some time :)

Comment: I guess. I mean, I would personally prefer to bounty the interesting ones rather than the easy ones. But we'll see. :)

Answer (score 6):

> ### JonathanReez
>
> Total number of bounties: **7**
>
> Total value of bounties: **600**

- Date - Question link - Bounty value - Validated by
- 1st April 2018 - [Can I travel to Austria on a new visa-free passport if I lost the passport that contained a long-term Austrian visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/97868/can-i-travel-to-austria-on-a-new-visa-free-passport-if-i-lost-the-passport-that) - 100 - Roddy
- 1st April 2018 - [Can a non-resident US citizen who has a driving license from a US state drive in another state using his foreign license?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/98942/can-a-non-resident-us-citizen-who-has-a-driving-license-from-a-us-state-drive-in) - 100 - Roddy
- 1st April 2018 - [How often do Spirit $9 Fares get posted?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/98911/how-often-do-spirit-9-fares-get-posted) - 100 - Roddy
- 2nd April 2018 - [How to prove sufficient funds when entering the US?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100328/how-to-prove-sufficient-funds-when-entering-the-us) - 100 - Roddy
- 3rd April 2018 - [What kind of items related to sex can be carried to UAE?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/102359/what-kind-of-items-related-to-sex-can-be-carried-to-uae) - 100 - mts
- 8th April 2018 -[Do I need to provide passport details when booking to travel via ferry or train from England to Netherlands?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104455/do-i-need-to-provide-passport-details-when-booking-to-travel-via-ferry-or-train) - 50 - ?
- 8th April 2018 - [What's the domestic to international connection procedure at Stansted airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/105986/whats-the-domestic-to-international-connection-procedure-at-stansted-airport) - 50 - ?

Answer (score 4):

> ### Roddy of the Frozen Peas
>
> Total number of bounties: **13**
>
> Total value of bounties: **750**

*Technically* my bounties went in late on the 31st but that was because the 1st was a religious holiday and I had obligations. Forgive me. :)

- Date - Question link - Bounty value - Validated by
- 1 April - [Traveling to Egypt if hiv+](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111434/) - 50 - JonathanReez
- 1 April - [Does Russia impose a limit on the number of visitor visas issued to tourists in a given year?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/107338/) - 50 - JonathanReez
- 1 April - [How strict are US National Park Cabin occupancy limits?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112067/) - 50 - JonathanReez
- 8 April - [Is kirpan allowed in Singapore MRT?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111068/) - 100 - JonathanReez
- 8 April - [Can I transit in Lisbon on my way to Oslo as a holder of an official Pakistani passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/107571/) - 50 - JonathanReez
- 8 April - [How widely accepted is the euro in Bosnia and Herzegovina?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/108658/) - 50 - JonathanReez
- 17 April - [How can a non-EU citizen living in the UK invite their friend to visit them?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/101951/) - 50 -
- 17 April - [My Indian visa has no photograph but my partner's visa does](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/108789/) - 50 -
- 17 April - [What is the difference between Canada B1 and V1 visas?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100625/) - 50 -
- 22 April - [Re-entry to the USA 6 years after a 5-year ban (deportation)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/107766/) - 50 -
- 25 April - [Observation regarding father's name change in passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111900) - 50 -
- 26 April - [I am American and have a D visa multi-entry for Italy](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111006) - 50 -
- 26 April - [Do I need a South African transit visa to go to Swaziland?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/110085/) - 50 -
- 27 April - [If the phone number of the contact person on my DS form changes, will that be an issue at port of entry?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111511/) - 50 -
- 30 April - [Cruising to Vietnam](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/113127/) - 50 -

Answer (score 3):

> ### Mark Mayo
>
> Total number of bounties: **14**
>
> Total value of bounties: **1200**

- Date - Question link - Bounty value - Validated by
- 1st April 2018 - [Through Check-In: JetBlue → Singapore → Lufthansa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100569/through-check-in-jetblue-%e2%86%92-singapore-%e2%86%92-lufthansa) - 50 - JonathanReez
- 1st April 2018 - [Is there a way to cancel "automatic tipping" on Carnival cruise before the last day?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111863/is-there-a-way-to-cancel-automatic-tipping-on-carnival-cruise-before-the-last) - 100 - JonathanReez
- 1st April 2018 - [How to receive an Australian tourist visa after getting denied once?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103433/how-to-receive-an-australian-tourist-visa-after-getting-denied-once) - 100 - JonathanReez
- 8th April 2018 - [Old passport validity when a new one has been issued](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111744/old-passport-validity-when-a-new-one-has-been-issued) - 50 -
- 8th April 2018 - [Is a certified copy of my marriage certificate sufficient proof of name change when traveling to the US?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112346/is-a-certified-copy-of-my-marriage-certificate-sufficient-proof-of-name-change-w) - 50 -
- 8th April 2018 - [In San Diego County do Compass cards automatically max out at a day pass rate? Should the total costs of rides eclipse that of a day pass?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/107499/in-san-diego-county-do-compass-cards-automatically-max-out-at-a-day-pass-rate-s) - 50 - 11th April 2018 - [Can I enter the US with a Green Card about to expire?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/104297/can-i-enter-the-us-with-a-green-card-about-to-expire) - 50 -
- 13 April 2018 - [How to book a flight when the exact return date is not known yet?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/108242/how-to-book-a-flight-when-the-exact-return-date-is-not-known-yet) - 50 -
- 13th April 2018 - [Must all citizenships be disclosed on a Global Entry application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112887/must-all-citizenships-be-disclosed-on-a-global-entry-application) - 50 -
- 16th April 2018 - [Can I travel to Germany with a criminal record?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/110884/can-i-travel-to-germany-with-a-criminal-record) - 50 -
- 17th April 2018 - [Is the Canal des Racó via ferrata route on Majorca open?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112219/is-the-canal-des-rac%c3%b3-via-ferrata-route-on-majorca-open) - 50 -
- 19th April 2018 - [Can I get a Mexican SIM card for a U.K. iPhone in Cancun Airport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/110258/can-i-get-a-mexican-sim-card-for-a-u-k-iphone-in-cancun-airport) - 50 -
- 22th April 2018 - [Which car rental companies in Northern Cyprus permit you to drive to the Republic?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/105166/which-car-rental-companies-in-northern-cyprus-permit-you-to-drive-to-the-republi) - 50 -
- 30th April 2018 - [Can I walk around Easter Island alone at night?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/113402/can-i-walk-around-easter-island-alone-at-night) - 50 -
- 30th April 2018 - [What is Two-Way Open Jaw?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/113798/what-is-two-way-open-jaw) - 100 -
- 30th April 2018 - [Which car rental companies in Northern Cyprus permit you to drive to the Republic?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/105166/which-car-rental-companies-in-northern-cyprus-permit-you-to-drive-to-the-republi) - 300 -