# Topicality: Reasons for delays

Tags: discussion, scope

Might we be able to come up with a consensus on the topicality of requests for reasons for delayed travel (esp. for compensation purposes)?

For an example, [What caused the delay of DL49 AMS-JFK 08-08-2017?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111539/what-caused-the-delay-of-dl49-ams-jfk-08-08-2017)

I would ask for opinion on both a generalized question, or one that appears to be simple curiosity (what delayed this flight by 12 hours?) and a more specific question about delay which is explicitly for assistance with a claim for compensation (linked question is an example).

Answer (score 6):

I vote you add the question along the lines of "How do I find the official reason for a flight delay" etc as canonical, and [ask it on March 31st](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4638/the-2018-easter-bounty-bonanza) so that we can bounty it the following day :D