# August 2019 Answerathon! Winner Willeke

Tags: discussion, fun, unanswered-questions, competitions

To give people time to enter, this will start on August 1st, UTC at midnight.

Rules: To stay in the competition, you must:

- answer an [unanswered question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered) not asked by you AND receive an upvote for your answer.
- **once the upvote has occurred (and not earlier)), edit the latest answer on this page for the date in question, and someone else can review and confirm.**
- IF there are no [unanswered questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered) at all (hah), then and only then can you answer a previously-answered question for your 'day'.
- IF the question you answer is marked as a duplicate on the same 'day', your answer is invalidated.

Each 'day' will last for 48 hours.  So August 1st-2nd inclusive is a day, August 3rd-4th is a day, and so on.

Miss a 'day' and you're out.

*However, please - if we finally hit a day where you can't answer something with a proper answer, ie with a citation or evidence or something useful to the author, don't post a weak answer on a question.*

I'll provide the sample answer template below for  August 1st. If you intend to enter, put your name there now.

Comment: What about closed for a reason other than duplicate?

Comment: If we get our upvote *after* the end of the "day", does it still count? For example, if I post an answer on August 1 that gets its first upvote on August 3, does that count as an Aug 1 answer, an Aug 3 answer, or nothing at all?

Comment: @RobertColumbia - it needs to have the upvote by the end of a 'day'. (they almost always do in comps as people review them).  I mean your answer might suck, and it doesn't deserve an upvote, so that's the criteria we have for now :)

Comment: @gparyani might think on that one.  Might just have to be if it's closed at all. Thoughts?

Comment: @MarkMayo Yeah, I agree with that.

Comment: If you answer on August 2, does the day run to the end of August 2 or August 3?

Comment: @Willeke - August 2nd.  You need to answer each 'day', and they go Aug1-Aug2, Aug3-Aug4 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

### September - 2 Participants left.

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

#### September 8

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [Forget to add a guest in non-free cancellation booking in booking.com](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/144858/22140) - Mark
2. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke) - [Accommodation with relatives on UK trip. Are they bearing cost of expenses?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/134797/accommodation-with-relatives-on-uk-trip-are-they-bearing-cost-of-expenses/145430#145430) - Joe

#### September 10

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [How does free baggage for Frequent Traveler status work?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/145541/how-does-free-baggage-for-frequent-traveler-status-work/145544#145544) - Willeke
2. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke) - [Food Allergies- Precooked/frozen meals to Netherlands](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/133960/food-allergies-precooked-frozen-meals-to-netherlands/145584#145584) - Joe

#### September 12

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [Permesso is not ready and student visa is expired](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/145587/permesso-is-not-ready-and-student-visa-is-expired/146668#146668) - Dirty-flow
2. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke) - [Use Nexus on same day as interview?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/131624/use-nexus-on-same-day-as-interview/146689#146689) -

#### September 14

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) - [Need advice regarding traveling to UK and France](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/122009/22140) - Willeke
2. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke) -
   [Cheapest way to exchange US Dollars for Japanese Yen in the UK](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/131007/cheapest-way-to-exchange-us-dollars-for-japanese-yen-in-the-uk/146756#146756) - Joe

#### September 16

1. [JoErNanO](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/22140/joernano) -
2. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke) - [Schengen visa granted for 2 months, duration of visit 45 days. Am I overstaying?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/130068/schengen-visa-granted-for-2-months-duration-of-visit-45-days-am-i-overstaying/146885#146885) - Joe

Comment: Let's use one post from now on.

Comment: Great plan, it will make life easier.

Comment: Actually, upon checking carefully, I am out because I got the upvote after the cutoff day.