# September 2019 Old Question Answerathon! Winner Willeke

Tags: discussion, fun, unanswered-questions, competitions

To give people time to enter, this will start on September 1st, UTC at midnight.

Rules: To stay in the competition, you must:

- answer an [unanswered question asked **ON OR BEFORE JUNE 30, 2019**](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered) not asked by you AND receive an upvote for your answer.
- **once the upvote has occurred (and not earlier), edit the latest answer on this page for the date in question, and someone else can review and confirm.**  If not edited in before the 'day' is up, you're out.  Reviews can occur after the fact, but if the review fails, you're out.
- IF there are no [unanswered questions](https://travel.stackexchange.com/unanswered) at all (hah), then and only then can you answer a previously-answered question for your 'day'.
- IF the question you answer is marked as a duplicate on the same 'day', your answer is invalidated.

Each 'day' will last for 48 hours.  So September 1st-2nd inclusive is a day, September 3rd-4th is a day, and so on.

Miss a 'day' and you're out.

*However, please - if we finally hit a day where you can't answer something with a proper answer, i.e. with a citation or evidence or something useful to the author, don't post a weak answer on a question.*

I'll provide the sample answer template below for  September 1st. If you intend to enter, put your name there now.

Comment: Mark, what is the latest moment you can edit your answer in here and still meet the deadline? Midnight 2 September, sometime 3 September?

Comment: @Willeke it's in the rules - " If not edited in before the 'day' is up, you're out.". So last minute you can do is 11.59pm, 2nd of Sep for the first 'day'.

Comment: I have one objection here: I mostly use the app since I'm often on the road, and it is hard to see exactly when the question was asked, especially if it has been modified after being asked. How can we handle this?

Comment: Do not use the app but the mobile phone version of the website. I do a lot of work on this site on my phone and no problems with seeing dates (and also less overall problems with the site.) Or just go for questions that have not been edited either.

Comment: @Willeke Yes the mobile browser version has more functionality than the app, but we can't force people to use it.

Comment: I got an accept without an upvote, does that count?

Comment: @Willeke I don't think it does.

Comment: I answered a question yesterday, didn't really know about this thread. Now i do. I think 48 hours are not up. Can i add that entry to any of the answers below? On mobile with a quick glance the 48 hour concept is a little confusing.

Comment: @HankyPanky first 'day' was Sep 1 to Sep 2, so presumably it wasn't in that window, so no.  But there'll be an October one too :)

Answer (score 3):

### September 1 -  6 entrants so far

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

1. [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/144915/101 - Daniil
2. [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/144921 - Willeke
3. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile) - [Partial accommodation evidence for UK standard visitor visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138820/partial-accommodation-evidence-for-uk-standard-visitor-visa/144931#144931) - Daniil
4. Joe - [Ryanair (late 2018) 10kg checked-in baggage dimension](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/122219/22140) - Willeke
5. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx)  - [Incorrect Parents name on ESTA](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/144944/4188) - Mark Mayo
6. [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/144951/10051 - Mark Mayo

### September 3 -  6 entrants remain

1. [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/145043/101 - chx
2. [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil) - [Is a passport or a national ID card valid on its expiration date?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/137908/is-a-passport-or-a-national-id-card-valid-on-its-expiration-date/145093#145093) - Willeke
3. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile) - [Can I use my Schengen visa for a different purpose and from different port of entry?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138275/can-i-use-my-schengen-visa-for-a-different-purpose-and-from-different-port-of-en/145072#145072) - Daniil
4. Joe - [Arrival 23:00 in Tangiers on Grimaldi Lines ferry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/122864/arrival-2300-in-tangiers-on-grimaldi-lines-ferry/145089#145089) - Willeke
5. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - [Overstayed in UK 10 years ago wants to visit UK under different nationality](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/145048/4188) - Mark
6. [Nean Der Thal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/10051/nean-der-thal) -

### September 5 -  5 entrants remain

1. [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/145199/101 - chx
2. [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/145223/89966 - Joe
3. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile) - [Schengen visa - Change of location](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138119/schengen-visa-change-of-location/145260#145260) - Mark
4. Joe - [UK Citizens transiting through T1 at Sydney Airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/129738/22140) - Willeke
5. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/145217/4188 - Joe

### September 7 -  5 entrants remain

1. [Mark Mayo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/101/mark-mayo)
2. [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil) - [What are the current requirements to get a visa to Thailand in Vientiane (Laos)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/128953/what-are-the-current-requirements-to-get-a-visa-to-thailand-in-vientiane-laos/145397#145397) - Willeke
3. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile) - [Vaping in Japan?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/135781/vaping-in-japan) - chx
4. Joe - [Schengen Visa and International Students](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/133739/22140) - Willeke
5. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/145364/4188 - Willeke

### September 9 -  4 entrants remain

1. [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/145477/89966 - Willeke
2. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile) - [Schengen visa main country for a mix of tourism/family visits](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/134033/schengen-visa-main-country-for-a-mix-of-tourism-family-visits/145486#145486) - chx
3. Joe - [Emirates trans-Tasman additional luggage costs?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/132774/22140) - chx
4. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/145456/4188 - Willeke

### September 11 -  4 entrants remain

1. [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/146599/89966 - Joe
2. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile) - [Ticketing norms for Schengen visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/133979/ticketing-norms-for-schengen-visa) - chx
3. Joe - [From Morocco to South Korea, transit in China](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/140959/from-morocco-to-south-korea-transit-in-china) - Dirty-flow
4. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/145592/4188 - Joe

### September 13 -  4 entrants remain

1. [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/146719/89966 - Willeke
2. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile) - [Is there any point in keeping paper versions of boarding passes, or are scans/pictures of them good enough?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/132311/is-there-any-point-in-keeping-paper-versions-of-boarding-passes-or-are-scans-pi/146725#146725) - Daniil
3. Joe - [Sister seeing off student exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/120397/22140) -  Willeke
4. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/146707/4188 - Mark Mayo

### September 15 -  4 entrants remain

1. [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil) -https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/146820/89966 - chx
2. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile) - [Booking Disney World in Orlando tickets online](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/132440/booking-disney-world-in-orlando-tickets-online/146884#146884) - Daniil
3. Joe - [Rejection of UK Visitor Visa for V 4.2 (e) WITH Sponsor - pre-application advice requested](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/122583/rejection-of-uk-visitor-visa-for-v-4-2-e-with-sponsor-pre-application-advice/146883#146883) -  Willeke
4. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/146851/4188 - Mark Mayo

### September 17 -  4 entrants remain

1. [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/146988/89966 - Willeke
2. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile) - [My friends flight was cancelled but mine wasn’t, what can I do?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/129850/the-flight-of-my-friends-was-cancelled-but-mine-was-not-anything-i-can-do/146980#146980) - Daniil
3. Joe -
4. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/146936/4188 - Willeke

### September 19 -  3 entrants remain

1. [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/147098/89966 - chx
2. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile) - [What is the allowed amount of electronics to be brought to USA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/129605/what-is-the-allowed-amount-of-electronics-to-be-brought-to-usa/147137#147137) - chx
3. [chx](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/4188/chx) - https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/147093/4188 - Daniil

Answer (score 0):

### September 21 -  2 entrants remain

**Remember to check the [current time in UTC](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=current+time+utc) to make sure your entry is valid.**

Name --------- Link to Answer in new question  -------- Reviewed by

### September 21

1. [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil) - [Transit visa at Incheon airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/140794/transit-visa-at-incheon-airport/147261#147261) - Willeke
2. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile) - [Canker sores after visiting Nigeria](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/126124/canker-sores-after-visiting-nigeria/147216#147216) - Daniil

### September 23

1. [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil) - [Can I visit outside Incheon Airport with these conditions?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/134553/can-i-visit-outside-incheon-airport-with-these-conditions/147334#147334)  - Willeke
2. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile) - [How do you operate an OV-Chipkaart Automaat?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/125817/how-do-you-operate-an-ov-chipkaart-automaat/147370#147370) - Daniil

### September 25

1. [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil) - [Philippine passport, based in UK](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/133540/philippine-passport-based-in-uk/147537#147537) - Willeke
2. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile) - [US citizen denied entry to the UK; will it go away if I renew my passport or get an enhanced drivers license?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/126756/us-citizen-denied-entry-to-the-uk-will-it-go-away-if-i-renew-my-passport-or-get/147524#147524) - Daniil

### September 27

1. [Daniil](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/89966/daniil) - [Can I travel around Europe with an expired student visa and Italian Permeso appointment receipt? I also have the expired Permeso card, will that help?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/130007/can-i-travel-around-europe-with-an-expired-student-visa-and-italian-permeso-appo/147653#147653) - Willeke -now closed as duplicate.
2. [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile) - [Incoming debit transactions in statements](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/140239/incoming-debit-transactions-in-statements/147663#147663) - Daniil