# April 2023 Photo Competition: Fountains

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

The theme for the April photo competition is "Fountains" (proposed by [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke?tab=profile)). This covers any photo of something designed to pour or jet water for artistic effect.

You may make your submission as an answer to this post. The standard rules for photo contests apply:

- Up to three photos per answer. Photos in the same answer should be of the same fountain.
- You can make up to three posts (attempts).
- Do not delete posts if you don't get votes: you posted it, stand by it. (You have two more attempts if your first one doesn't work out.)
- All submissions should have a line with when and where the photo(s) was/were taken, along with a description of the subject.
- The photo has to be taken by the person who posted it, or by a travel partner (needs to be named).
- Keep it nice, non-offensive, and non-NSFW.
- If you disagree with a photo, please consider leaving a comment on it or bringing it up in chat. For the purposes of judging, only upvotes will be considered; downvotes will not affect the score of the photo.
- The photo may have been taken any time.
- The photo competition will begin on the publication of this post, and continue until the end of the month (again in UTC). If there is no tie for the highest number of upvotes at the end of the month, the winner will be announced then; if there is, the voting period may extend beyond the month.

If you'd like to suggest a theme for a future photo competition, please add it to the [list of possible photo competition topics](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5048/11329). Also, you can join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) to help us make the decision on which topic to choose.

---

### Results

jcklopp wins the bragging rights for the highest-voted submission this month, of the Triton Fountain in Malta.

MattAllegro wins the virtual prize, for their collection of photos also of the Triton Fountain. I found that the two submissions complement each other well and the final photo of sunglasses seemed very unique to me.

Comment: It was windy on that day and my girlfriend was like: "hey be careful or your glasses are gonna fly!"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll also have a go with [Triton Fountain](https://maps.app.goo.gl/zYdU1D9CJetmKSQi9) in Valletta, Malta. I took this pictures in 2019 and 2020.

[image: Triton Fountain 1]

[image: Triton Fountain 2]

[image: Triton Fountain 3]

Comment: Congratulations! Your submission wins the virtual prize for this month.

Comment: @gparyani wow, thank you!! I'm so glad it was appreciated :-)

Answer (score 7):

The Triton Fountain in Valletta on the island of Malta. Photo taken on March 18th, 2023. Recent restorations which removed a temporary central pillar were completed a few years ago. This fountain is just outside the main city gate.

[image: The Maltese Tritons]

Comment: I was thinking of posting a photo of this fountain [when it's lit up at night](https://www.flickr.com/photos/mlcastle/52182836598), but there are so many fountains in the world I'll find a different one to post.

Comment: This is the highest voted post at the end of April.

Answer (score 6):

[image: fountain]

A fountain amongst the plant life at the at the Butchart Gardens on Vancouver Island, near Victoria, BC, Canada. I took this photo on October 23, 2016.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Fountain at VDNKh]

This is the "Friendship of Peoples Fountain" in Moscow. Each of the 16 golden statues represents a member republic of the USSR, holding the primary crop grown there. I took this picture in May 2019.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Fountain in Barcelona]

This fountain was my highlights at the beautiful Parc de la Ciutadella in Barcelona. I took this photo in March of 2019.

Answer (score 2):

The Emperor fountain at [Chatworth house](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chatsworth_House), Derbyshire, UK.
[image]

Photo taken 9 May 2012, the fountain is likely only half the height it can reach, as the man made lake at the top of the hill that powers it is not unlimited and they prefer not to drain it on normal days.

Answer (score 2):

Lille, France, the open space between [the Palais de Beaux Arts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palais_des_Beaux-Arts_de_Lille) and the Prefecture, one fountain and two views of it.

[image: multi spout fountain, the water catching the light]

[image: multi spout fountain, the carved stone also well visible]

Both photos taken 21 May 2022, with only a few minutes between the takes but from opposite sides of the water feature.

Answer (score 2):

This second one is not so popular instead: [Fontana dei Quattro Cavalli](https://maps.app.goo.gl/xfD4eeM7pRu9sKG19) (*Four Horses Fountain*) in Rimini, Italy. Again I shot these photos in July 2021.

[image: Rimini Italy 1]

[image: Rimini Italy 2]

Answer (score 2):

Fountain at [the Patuxai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patuxai) in Vientiane, Laos. Not the best pictures, but still an interesting place. Photos taking in August of 2009 using a Supra DC-6900.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Fontana Di Trevi, Rome, Italy. Triton, Oceanus, Hippocampus, Aqua Virgo and the rest decorate this fountain of hope, where the main theme is the water purification:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Fiumi Fountain, Piazza di Navona, Rome, Italy. The fountain symbolizes the 4 rivers/continents that the Pope has power on, i.e. Ganges (Asia), Nile (Africa), Danube (Europe), Rio de la Plata (Americas).

Notice how Ganges is depicted on the left, showcasing its navigability. Nile is depicted with his head hidden, because at that time its source was of unknown location.

An Egyptian obelisk stands tall at the fountain's centre.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am a day late but I took this photo today, at a business park in Cambridgeshire, UK.

[image]

There is also a water feature which cascades into the pond at the back left.